# Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, profile

Is `~/.bashrc`  the only place to specify user specific environment variables, aliases, modifications to `PATH` variable, etc?

I ask because it seems that `~/.bashrc` seems to be `bash`-only, but other shells exist too…

Answer (score 112, accepted):

The file `$HOME/.profile` is used by a number of shells, including bash, sh, dash, and possibly others.

From the bash man page:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, ... it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.   After  reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.

csh and tcsh explicitly don't look at `~/.profile` but those shells are kinda antiquated.

Comment: Zsh by default does not read .profile. That's why I deleted my previous answer stating this. Zsh only reads .profile when it is invoked by a symbolic link named sh.

Comment: tcsh is still popular in some enviroments.

Comment: fschmitt: thanks for the correction; fixed.  Maciej Piechotka: I have no doubt that's true; however it is also possible (though complicated) to make *rc scripts that import particular other rc scripts based on the shell they are running under.

Comment: For this way to work, users need to ensure that each shell is a login shell.  For example, in Gnome Terminal, go to Profile -> Title and Command, and enable `Run command as a login shell`.  You also need to remove `~/.bash_profile`, or make it source `~/.profile`.

Comment: @fschmitt You can also source `$HOME/.profile` from inside your Zsh `.zshrc`, too. I tend to put all my portable shell things in `.profile` and then I can share it around any environment I might hop between.

Comment: For amusement &&/|| historical value, I present: [The BNR Standard Login](https://google.com/search?q="the+bnr+standard+login") -- which used `~/.bnrrc` to add required shell configs for various tools to **both** sh and csh.

Answer (score 78):

`~/.profile` is the right place for environment variable definitions and for non-graphical programs that you want to run when you log in (e.g. `ssh-agent`, `screen -m`). It is executed by your login shell if that is a Bourne-style shell (sh, ksh, bash). Zsh runs `~/.zprofile` instead, and Csh and tcsh run `~/.login`.

If you log in under an X display manager (xdm, gdm, kdm, ...), whether `~/.profile` is run depends how your display manager and perhaps desktop environment were configured by your distribution. If you log in under a “custom session”, that usually executes `~/.xsession`.

`~/.bashrc` is the right place for bash-specific settings, such as aliases, functions, shell options and prompts. As the name indicates, it is specific to bash; csh has `~/.cshrc`, ksh has `~/.kshrc`, and zsh has <drumroll> `~/.zshrc`.

See also:

- [Difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile)
- [Which setup files should be used for setting up environment variables with bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/183845/which-setup-files-should-be-used-for-setting-up-environment-variables-with-bash)
- [Zsh not hitting `~/.profile`](https://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile)

Comment: Don't forget zsh also has `.zlogin` in addition to `.zprofile` which runs *after* `.zshrc` (but only for login shells). See the [ZSH FAQ](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq03.html)

Answer (score 38):

There is no common file, but you can make every shell read from a common file.

1. `bash` reads from `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`
2. `zsh` reads from `.zprofile` *and* `.zshrc`
3. `ksh` reads from `.profile` or `$ENV`

So here's what I do:

**`~/.env`**

```
# Put environment variables here, e.g.
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

**`~/.shrc`**

```
test -f "$HOME/.env" && . "$HOME/.env"

# Put interactive shell setup here, e.g.
alias ll='ls -l'
PS1='$PWD$ '
set -o emacs
```

**`~/.bashrc`**

```
test -f ~/.shrc && source ~/.shrc

# Put any bash-specific settings here, e.g.
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
shopt -s extglob
IGNOREEOF=yes
```

**`~/.zshenv`**

```
# Put any zsh-specific settings for non-interactive and interactive sessions, e.g.
setopt braceexpand
setopt promptsubst
setopt shwordsplit
```

**`~/.zshrc`**

```
test -f ~/.shrc && source ~/.shrc

# Put any zsh-specific interactive settings here, e.g.
HISTFILE=~/.zsh_history
setopt ignoreeof
```

**`~/.profile`**

```
# Interactive sub-shells source .env, unless this is bash or zsh,
# because they already sourced .env in .bashrc or .zshrc.
if test -z "$BASH_VERSION" -a -z "$ZSH_VERSION" || test -n "$BASH_VERSION" -a \( "${BASH##*/}" = "sh" \)
then
    test -f "$HOME"/.env && . "$HOME"/.env
fi

# The name is confusing, but $ENV is ksh's config file for interactive sessions,
# so it's equivalent to .bashrc or .zshrc.
# Putting this here makes running an interactive ksh from any login shell work.
test -f "$HOME"/.shrc && export ENV="$HOME"/.shrc

# Put any login shell specific commands here, e.g.
ssh-add
stty -ixon
```

**`~/.bash_profile`**

```
source ~/.bashrc
source ~/.profile
```

**`~/.zlogin`**

```
# zsh sources .zshrc automatically, only need to source .profile
source ~/.profile
```

**`~/.zprofile`**

```
(empty)
```

---

If you have root access to the system, another way is to set up `pam_env`.

You can put

```
session optional pam_env.so user_envfile=.env
```

in the relevant `/etc/pam.d` file (e.g. `/etc/pam.d/common-session` on Debian), and then when the user logs in, `PAM` will read environment variables from `~/.env`.

Note that `pam_env` basically only supports `VAR=value` entries.

More info:

- [pam_env](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_env.html)

Answer (score 15):

There is no such thing like a environment config file for different shells, because its even shell specific how they are defined.

In csh you use `setenv` in bash you use `export` to define them.

Anyway you could write your own config file and include it with `source` in the dotfiles of your shells.