# How can I install the `ll` command on Mac OS X?

Tags: shell, osx, alias

I'm using Mac OS X. When I SSH into servers I find the `ll` command useful, but it's not available on my local machine. How can I install it?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

MacOS:

```
alias ll='ls -lG'
```

Linux:

```
alias ll='ls -l --color=auto'
```

Stick that in [the appropriate startup file for your shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3085/86440), *e.g.* `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`. To apply the setting, `source` the file, or quit and restart your terminal.

Comment: It worked!, anyway `--color=auto` parameter made an error. Other parts worked well.

Comment: Ah right, [BSD ls doesn't support `--color`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/ls.1.html).

Comment: One more, I had to add the command `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc` to make it work. Maybe this is Mac OS X specific.

Comment: You need `alias ll='ls -lG'` for the same effect in macosx.

Comment: I needed to add `alias ll='ls -lG'` to my ~/.bash_profile to make it work (in Lion, if that matters)

Comment: Even lazier: `$ echo "alias ll='ls -lG'" >> ~/.bashrc`

Comment: On root user it didn't work for me, any idea why?

Comment: @Eonil Macs use ~/.bash_profile, but you could add source ~/.bashrc into that file to make bashrc get sourced in.

Comment: I use ```alias ll='ls -alG'``` as I like to see the hidden files as well.

Comment: And after you added the alias, saved and exited do a `source ~/.bashrc` to activate it without exiting Bash.

Comment: I only have ~/.bash_history and ~/.bash_sessions in my new Macbook. Ideas?

Comment: For those who are finding this answer in 2021 - you need to add it to .zprofile instead of .bash_profile. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310864/4282321

Comment: I had to add in ~/.bash_profile . OS. -MacOS BigSur, 11.2.2

Comment: I am suggesting to add `-a` - `alias ll='ls -alG'`

Answer (score 61):

In OS X 10.9.5 since Mavericks (and at least up to El Capitan) you have to add an alias command to your **.bash_profile** file in your home folder:

```
~/.bash_profile
```

which is equivalent to your user path at

```
/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/.bash_profile
```

To see that file in finder you have to activate the display of hidden files (e.g. using the app InVisible). Otherwise you can simply use your terminal to locate it and edit it with nano:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Then add an alias command to the end of that file. The standard ll alias would be

```
alias ll='ls -lG'
```

but I prefer

```
alias ll='ls -lGaf'
```

which also shows all hidden files (starting with a dot) and sorts the output case-insensitive.

Don't forget to **restart** your terminal app after the changes.

Comment: you don't need to restart the terminal, it is enough to use `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload the new settings

Answer (score 11):

macOS with zsh shell should put

```
alias ll='ls -lG'
```

to *~/.zshrc*
instead of *~/.bash_profile* nor *~/.bashrc*

Comment: very good one. 
I like to use alias ll='ls -laG'
So, the files size is displayed in MB, KB, etc

Answer (score 9):

Run `type ll` to see where the `ll` command is coming from. `ll` is not a standard command, but many distributions predefine it to an [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_%28command%29) for `ls` with some preset options. The output of `type ll` gives you the definition of the alias, or you can look for it in your shell configuration file (`~/.bashrc` if your shell is bash). Copy the definition to `~/.bashrc` on the other machine.

Bash handles its configuration file in a slightly odd way: it loads `~/.bashrc` in all interactive shells except the ones that are also login shells. Bash only loads `~/.bash_profile` (if it exists, otherwise `~/.profile`) in a login shell. To make sure that your `.bashrc` is read when it should be, put this line in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `alias ll='ls -lG'` to your `~/.profile` with your favorite `$EDITOR`.

With this method, remember that you'll have to start a new terminal session (or `source ~/.profile` to be able to use `ll`).

Answer (score 6):

On macOS Ventura:

```
echo "alias ll='ls -la'" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Don't forget to close and reopen Terminal after that.

As it's explained in the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310864/1833895):

> Apple has changed the default shell to zsh. Therefore you have to
> rename your configuration files.
> .bashrc is now .zshrc and .bash_profile is now .zprofile.

The difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` files explained in this [article](https://medium.com/@kingnand.90/what-is-the-difference-between-bash-profile-and-bashrc-d4c902ac7308).

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to apply in all accounts, you can also put

```
alias ll='ls -lG'
```

in `/etc/profile`.

Comment: Does OSX even have an `/etc`?

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the best of all answers:

Mac OS X (tested on El Capitan)

```
echo "alias ll='ls -lGaf'" >> ~/.bash_profile 
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Linux

```
echo "alias ll='ls -la --color=auto'" >> ~/.bash_profile
source  ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 2):

(MacOS Mojave Example)

1. Open the hidden `.bash_profile` file in the Vim editor:

   ```
   vim ~/.bash_profile
   ```
2. Jump to the last character of the file by pressing capital <kbd>G</kbd> and then <kbd>$</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>o</kbd> to add a new line to the file.
4. Insert your new alias like:

   ```
   alias ll='ls -lG'
   ```
5. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert mode of Vim.
6. Type following to write your new changes and exit the editor:

   ```
   :wq
   ```
7. Reopen terminal and you should be able to use the alias `ll`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the rep points yet to comment directly on someone else's comment but, I just wanted to clarify that `"alias ll='ls -lGaf'"` is partly redundant.  Using -f automatically enables -a as well.  You can verify this in the man page for `ls`.  So, all that's truly needed is `"alias ll='ls -lGf'"`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is missing from several answers is that this is shell-dependent. If you're using the system default shell on 10.14 on below, which is bash, then references to (.)bash_profile are correct. Modifying /etc/profile would create the alias for sh for all users (but not in bash).

If you have switched, for example, to zsh, then making a system-wide change requires adding the alias to /etc/zprofile. If you wanted to make the change for only your user, then you could add it to ~/.zprofile