# Run xterm with login shell or not?

Tags: shell, login, xterm

Per default `xterm` starts an interactive shell. But you can also configure it to start an interactive **login-shell**.

That means that with starting an `xterm` you get the same kind of shell like logging in via ssh/virtual console/su.

What are the advantages/disadvantages configuring a *login-shell* in xterm?

I can think of:

- `uptime`, `w`, `last` etc. report as many users as `xterm`'s are open. (advantage?)
- `bash` only sources `.login`, `.profile`, `/etc/profile.d` when started as *login-shell*
- `zsh` has similar files which it reads when started as *login-shell* - but on my system they are empty by default

Related `xterm` man page section:

> ```
>    -ls     This  option  indicates  that  the shell that is started in the
>            xterm window will be a login shell (i.e., the  first  character
>            of  argv[0]  will  be  a  dash, indicating to the shell that it
>            should read the user's .login or .profile).
> ```

There is also a resource:

> ```
>   loginShell (class LoginShell)
>            Specifies whether or not the shell to  be  run  in  the  window
>            should be started as a login shell.  The default is “false.”
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running a login shell in the terminal will execute any program you put in your `.profile`, even if you'd expect that program to run only once per session (for example, `ssh-agent` and other keyrings). Running a login shell will overwrite environment variables that you've set in your session or in the terminal's parent process.

The biggest problem people who run a login shell in terminals experience is that they usually don't set their environment variables when they log into the GUI. The drawback of this is that the environment variables are thus only available in programs started from a terminal, not from programs directly started through the GUI. If you do set your environment variables at login time, setting them again in each terminal is at best pointless and sometimes a problem as seen above.

See also [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](https://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980#183980), [Alternative to .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085), 
and quite a few questions I've seen on Stack Exchange that would have been avoided if the asker had set environment variables per session.