# Xterm not loading color schemes

Tags: linux, xterm, crunchbang

I work a lot with vim and decided to switch to cli version, I chose `xterm` because its the only terminal I know of that properly recognizes <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts (and I have lots of those bound in vim).

My problem is that `xterm` doesn't load config file on startup. I have it in `.Xresources` file in my home directory (I also tried moving the contents of it to `.Xdefaults` but to no avail). When I type `xrdb .Xresources` it loads all the settings normally, also typing `xrdb -query -all` shows up proper terminal settings.
I tried including that line in `.xinitrc` file and Openbox autorun  (I work in Crunchbang distro where it is main window manager) but it doesn't work either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to fix that?

My `.Xresources` file looks like this:

```
!XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
!UXTerm*termName: xterm-256color

! Colors

*background: #181818
*foreground: #c0c0c0
*cursorColor: #93a1a1

!! black dark/light
*color0: #121212
*color8: #2e3436

!! red dark/light
*color1: #a35b66
*color9: #ab6b74

!! green dark/light
*color2: #99ab6f
*color10: #acb972

!! yellow dark/light
*color3: #ca9733
*color11: #ccaa69

!! blue dark/light
*color4: #495d6e
*color12: #687987

!! magenta dark/light
*color5: #825969
*color13: #977381

!! cyan dark/light
*color6: #839191
*color14: #98a4a4

!! white dark/light
*color7: #e0e0e0
color15: #e5e5e5

!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*multiClickTime: 500
! Use a nice truetype font and size by default... 

! Every shell is a login shell by default (for inclusion of all necessary environment variables)
xterm*loginshell: true

! I like a LOT of scrollback...
xterm*savelines: 16384
UXTerm*faceSize: 8
UXTerm*cursorBlink: true
! double-click to select whole URLs :D
xterm*charClass: 33:48,36-47:48,58-59:48,61:48,63-64:48,95:48,126:48

! right hand side scrollbar...
xterm*rightScrollBar: false
xterm*ScrollBar: false

! stop output to terminal from jumping down to bottom of scroll again
xterm*scrollTtyOutput: false
```

Comment: I don't think that setting `*loginshell` is doing what you think it does. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35320/run-xterm-with-login-shell-or-not

Answer (score 4):

Check what files `xterm` processes when you run it. Typically these include:

```
$HOME/.Xdefaults-`hostname`
{$HOME,/etc/X11/app-defaults}/{<locale-full>,<locale-lang>,}/XTerm{,-color}
```

Check the output of `strace xterm` to get a full list for your system.

My guess is that you need to `ln -s ~/.Xdefaults ~/.Xdefaults-$(hostname)`.

You also might want to tidy up your .Xdefaults file in two ways:

1. pick a caps style and keep it consistently
2. use prefixes like `xterm*` or `VT100*` throughout the settings

A good idea also might be creating a simple `.Xdefaults` file contining just `#includes` for per-application Xresources, i.e.:

```
#include <path/to/XTerm.xresources>
#include <path/to/UXTerm.xresources>
#include <path/to/whatever_else.xresources>
```

since it scales better.

Answer (score 3):

A setting like `*background: #181818` applies to all background colors in all widgets in all applications that use X resources. However, if an application has an explicit setting for its widgets somewhere, this more specific setting overrides the general setting `*background`. In practice, a general setting like `*background` is not useful.

All entries in `~/.Xresources` should start with the class name of the application. This is usually the program name with initial caps. For xterm (including xterm with Unicode support, unless you're running an antique), the class name is `XTerm`. So change your `~/.Xresources` to

```
XTerm*background: #181818
XTerm*foreground: #c0c0c0
XTerm*cursorColor: #93a1a1
…
```

If this still doesn't take effect, try a more specific setting that explicitly lists the widget you want to change:

```
XTerm.VT100.background: #181818
XTerm.VT100.foreground: #c0c0c0
XTerm.VT100.cursorColor: #93a1a1
…
```

If you use `xterm` (lowercase) instead of `XTerm`, then the settings only apply when you run a program (xterm or any other) with the instance name `xterm`, but not when you run e.g. `xterm -name foo`.

Oh, and [don't set `loginShell`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35320/run-xterm-with-login-shell-or-not/35352#35352): that runs a login shell in each terminal, which causes more trouble than it solves. Your environment variables need to be set for your whole session anyway, not in each terminal.