# Setting locale for user

Tags: environment-variables, locale, i18n

I'd like to set a locale for my user different than system locale.

By putting `export LANG=en_US.utf8` in `.bashrc` I could do that for the shells, but still it's not working for applications not started via a shell (i.e. the desktop environment, LXDE, which is started through GDM3).

Is there any way to set a different default locale (used by any kind of application, even if not started via bash) for my user?

Comment: Not `.bashrc`. Usually `~/.profile`, but unfortunately there's no universal answer. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/3085#3085)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X login is annoyingly inconsistent about which startup file names are used.   On the system I'm using you would just need to modify `$HOME/.xsessionrc`.   But it does vary.   I generally put my environment variable settings in a separate file and source that from `.profile` and `.xsessionrc`.

If `.xsessionrc` does not work for you, check the documentation or read the scripts in `/etc/X11/`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting any locale incorrectly can produce unwanted results, but first and foremost I would refrain from using `en_US.utf8` - instead use `en_US.UTF-8`.

Lowercase `.utf8` may be usefull in certain programming environments but a normal user would need the correct value.

Edit `.xsessionrc`,`.bashrc` and/or `.profile` to include the line(s) they may need, such as these:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_NAME=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=es_ES.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
PAPERSIZE=a4
LANGUAGE=en_US
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Note , I have different values for different locale types. Each to their own! Remove those you don't need and [*look here for more info.*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/locale.1.html)