# Issues with .bash_profile and terminal commands

Tags: bash, osx, alias, bashrc

I added some data to my `.bash_profile` to run two aliases ruby version 19 and the proper gems. As soon as I added the data I could not longer run any commands such as the [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) command port nor the command mate to run [TextMate](http://macromates.com/). As soon as I deactivated `.bash_profile` and `.bash_login` and even `.bash_history` all was well again. `.bash_history` got regenerated and soon thereafter I got `.bash_profile` reinstated with my badly needed aliases, but then I lost the option to run these commands again. Here is some of the output of all these files:

```
jaspersmbp:~ jasper$ cat .bash_profile
    alias ruby='/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9'
    alias gem='/opt/local/bin/gem'
jaspersmbp:~ jasper$ cat .bash_login
jaspersmbp:~ jasper$ cat .bashrc
    HISTFILESIZE=1000000000
    HISTSIZE=1000000
jaspersmbp:~ jasper$ cat .profile
    #Django path
    export PATH=/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:$PATH
    # Apache alias
    alias apacherestart='sudo /opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k restart'
    #Subversion OSX for Eclips Joomla Development
    export PATH=/opt/subversion/bin:$PATH
    #Test
    #echo $PATH
    ##
    # Your previous /Users/jasper/.profile file was backed up as /Users/jasper/.profile.macports-saved_2012-05-18_at_09:47:58
    ##
    # MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-05-18_at_09:47:58: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
    export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
    # Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Does anyone know why making `.bash_profile` active anihilates the use of commands such as mate and port? I really need `.bash_profile` to work so I can use aliases and I need MacPorts port command for all kinds software.

Comment: I'm confused: is MacPorts generating some of your dotfiles? If so, exactly which files? This seems like a terrible idea..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like MacPort is generating your configuration files, and messing up your `PATH` and such. The easiest way to fix this is by doing it yourself - disable MacPort generation/creation of the dotfiles concerning your path and aliases, remove the `.bash_profile` and `.profile` files and then append the following to the `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# define aliases
alias ruby='ruby1.9'
alias apacherestart='sudo apachectl -k restart'

# define hist properties
HISTFILESIZE=1000000000
HISTSIZE=1000000

# define path to programs
PATH=/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/apache2/bin/:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:$PATH

# define manpath
MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH

# export env vars
export HISTFILESIZE HISTSIZE PATH MANPATH
```

Start a new terminal and run `echo $PATH` to check that everything is in there and then test a couple of commands installed under `/opt/local/bin`. Since all the directories in the above `PATH=` statement are now in your `PATH` you don't need aliases that use absolute paths to the binary - for example you don't need the alias for `gem` anymore because you can just run `gem`.

Update: If your `~/.bashrc` is not sourced put `source ~/.bashrc` in a clean `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: Here is my current PATH `$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin`
I will try your suggestion. I do need to keep MacPorts running, but reading your explanation it seems I can. macPorts did generate the files to make using the port command.

Comment: Only somehow the alias `alias ruby='/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9'
` does not run Ruby 1.9 yet, but still grabs the old Ruby

Comment: When I also removed .profile I lost port and mate. Here is my current path `echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin` and path in .bashrc `PATH=/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/apache2/bin/:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:$PATH`

Comment: @rhand See my update in the answer.

Comment: Cool. All commands seem back. Only got one path warning concerning gems running:
`sudo gem install --user-install typhoeus
Password:
Fetching: typhoeus-0.4.2.gem (100%)m
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:438: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/jasper/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed typhoeus-0.4.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for typhoeus-0.4.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for typhoeus-0.4.2...`

Comment: Added gem to my path in .bashrc: 
`PATH=/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/apache2/bin/:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:/Users/jasper/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:$PATH`, but still get the same error that I need to install typhoeus. Probaly another issue as there is no longer a path error mentioned. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @rhand, hesse: don't put environment variable settings in `.bashrc`, they belong in `.bash_profile` or `.profile`. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/3085#3085)

Answer (score 1):

Bash reads `~/.bash_profile` if it exists, and `~/.profile` if it doesn't. Hence when you created `~/.bash_profile`, your `~/.profile` was no longer used.  Your aliases aren't specific to bash as opposed to other shells, so you might as well put them in `~/.profile`.

Also, you start an interactive login bash, bash reads `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` (the bash-specific session startup script, or the generic shell session startup script if it doesn't exist), but not `~/.bashrc` (the interactive bash startup script). So put these two lines in your `~/.bash_profile` to load everything as it should be:

```
. ~/.profile
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe it's `$PATH` problem? Have you check it before & after?

Comment: Here is my PATH:
`$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/subversion/bin:/opt/local/bin:opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/django/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin`
Not sure if there is an issue there. You and @hesse do think there is so there must be. Still pretty green in this area.