# .bashrc and .bash_profile not executed

Tags: bash, rhel, bashrc

I'm running RHEL5.  I added simple alias command into `~/.bashrc`.  When I start a new terminal, nothing happens but `source ~/.bashrc` works so I know the syntax is correct.  I also modified/source-tested `~/.bash_profile` but it's not executed on terminal startup either.  `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` don't exist on my system.

here is my `~/.bashrc`

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc fi

# User specific aliases and functions
alias hi=hello
```

And my `~/.bash_profile`

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

Comment: How do you start a new terminal? If you start it by clicking onto an icon this should be okay as this will start a non-login shell. Are you sure you are inside a bash shell? Type echo $SHELL, the system's response should be /bin/bash. On http://www.linuxintro.org/wiki/Boot_process#user_starts_a_shell I describe that the process sourcing .bashrc is login. Can you just call bash and see if .bashrc is being executed?

Comment: That should be `.bash_profile`, not `.bash_profiles`. Was that a typo?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work

Comment: @terdon Yes it's a typo, fixed.

Comment: Thanks. Now, please confirm that 1) you're running bash and not another shell and 2) your terminal is not configured to start login shells. If neither `.bashrc` nor `.bash_profile` is being sourced, you're likely not running bash at all.

Comment: @ThorstenStaerk `echo $SHELL` = /bin/zsh

Comment: @terdon See the directly above comment.  That's why `~/.bashrc` isn't being run.  Is there a `zsh` equivalent?

Comment: Yes, it's `~/.zshrc`. In that case, I am closing your question as non-reproducible since it is unlikely to help future visitors. If you have a new `zsh` question, feel free to ask it.

Answer (score 5):

`~/.bashrc` is only executed for non-login shells, check your terminal settings:
`Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command -> "Run command as a login shell`

The usual `~/.profile` loads `~/.bashrc` if it is available, if - assuming `$BASH_VERSION` is present in your environment.

Keep in mind though that `~/.profile` is ignored if if there's `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` in your home and that, as a result of it being ignored, `~/.bashrc` isn't sourced, too.

Comment: You're probably right about the OP starting login shells but note that the "usual" `.profile` does not source `.bashrc`. It does on some systems but it is not the case everywhere and is not true on the SuSe system I just checked. Your last line is wrong, `.profile` itself is ignored if either `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` exist, this has nothing to do with whether or not `.bashrc` is read by `.profile`.

Comment: @terdon Yes, that's what I meant - I'll try to reprhase it in an edit.

Comment: In recent-ish Debian default files, `.profile` checks if it's running Bash, and if so, loads `.bashrc`. In the glacial terms of Debian development, this is a relatively recent arrangement, and certainly not generalizable to other distributions. Perhaps Red Hat had this for a longer time.