# Bash aliases not picked up on initial login

Tags: bash, login, bashrc

I'm running Debian 8.5 (Jessie) on a virtualbox vm. I have some bash aliases that I can't get to run when I initially login to my vm. However, when I run  `bash` from inside the shell, then they work. How can I configure my system to get them to work on startup?

```
yourstruly@mate:~$ tail ~/.bash_aliases
alias quit='exit'
alias reboot='sudo shutdown -r now'
alias halt='sudo shutdown -h now'

yourstruly@mate:~$ halt
-bash: halt: command not found
yourstruly@mate:~$ bash
yourstruly@mate:~$ halt
Connection to localhost closed by remote host.
Connection to localhost closed.
```

I have put lines in `.bashrc` to include `.bash_aliases`.

```
yourstruly@mate:~$ tail ~/.bashrc

if [ -f ~/.bash_include ]; then
  . ~/.bash_include
fi

if [ -f ~/.bash_alias ]; then
  . ~/.bash_alias
fi
```

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't my ~/.bash_profile work?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When bash starts an interactive **login** shell, it runs the first one found of the following files: `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`.

By contrast, `~/.bashrc` is only run for interactive **non-login** shells.

The solution is to source `~/.bashrc` in whichever of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` you actually use.  Add a line like this:

```
if [[ $- = *i* ]]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

The special variable `$-` contains the active shell options, and interactive shells include `i` in the list of active options. So this sources `~/.bashrc` for interactive shells and only for interactive shells.