# How to make the command in /etc/profile be found?

Tags: bash

Os: debian9.

```
touch /home/test/test.log
```

There is a simple function write-date in /etc/profile.

```
write-date(){
    date >>  /home/test/test.log
    }
```

Create a service running at reboot or shutdown.

```
vim  /etc/systemd/system/test.service  

[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/test/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The simple function write-date in /home/test/test.sh.

```
vim  /home/test/test.sh
write-date
```

Enable the test.service.

```
sudo systemctl enable test.service
```

Reboot my pc and check log of test.service

```
sudo journalctl -u test
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-02-01 00:03:59 HKT, end at Thu 2018-02-01 00:15:54 HKT. --
Feb 01 00:04:04 test systemd[1]: Starting Run command at shutdown...
Feb 01 00:04:05 test bash[438]: /home/test/test.sh: line 3: write-date: command not found
Feb 01 00:04:11 test systemd[1]: test.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Feb 01 00:04:11 test systemd[1]: Failed to start Run command at shutdown.
Feb 01 00:04:11 test systemd[1]: test.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 01 00:04:11 test systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

How to make the command in /etc/profile be found ?

```
cat -vet /home/test/test.sh
$
$
    write-date$
    $
$
```

Comment: From what you show, you have the function _defined_ but never _invoked_.

Comment: @DopeGhoti That doesn't really explain the "command not found".  However, I wonder if `/home` still exists at the point when the service is invoked? I don't know much about systemd, but `/home` might be unmounted at shutdown and reboot on some systems, I presume?

Comment: There's two function definitions for write-date, one in /home/test/test.sh and one in /etc/profile, and as DopeGhoti said, you don't appear to be calling it. Also, /etc/profile is only (automatically) read for *login* shells, which a systemd-invoked script would *not* be.

Comment: Two blank lines on the top.

Comment: The content you showed with `vim  /home/test/test.sh` and the one with `cat` are completely different,

Comment: Sorry for my typo in  /home/test/test.sh , i want /home/test/test.sh to call write-date function from /etc/profile,please try to open an account in debian9 and with my code above to check what happens  in your  pc.

Comment: See also [Why doesn't my ~/.bash_profile work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/88106/80216)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to explicitly tell your service that it needs to source `/etc/profile`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Run command at shutdown
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/profile
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/bash  /home/test/test.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note the `EnvironmentFile` line.

Comment: What does  `=-` means in `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/profile`? What does `minus` (-) means in `=-`?

Comment: It means:  read the file if it's there, but continue to try to start up without it.

Comment: AFAIK `EnvironmentFile` doesn't support scripts like `/etc/profile`. Only key value pairs.