# Why bash does not update Java path without running source ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: bash, osx, java

I am using Mac, and `$JAVA_HOME` environment path is set in `~/.bash_profile` like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

After I updated Java, `bash` kept trying to find Java from the older version.

I had to run `source ~/.bash_profile` to tell bash the new Java path every time I open a new terminal. Is there any configuration overrides my setting in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: I would have said this was a duplicate of [Why doesn't my ~/.bash_profile work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88106/why-doesnt-my-bash-profile-work), except that [Why are interactive shells on OSX login shells by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119627/why-are-interactive-shells-on-osx-login-shells-by-default) suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A change made to `~/.bash_profile` will only be seen in new shell sessions (new terminal windows). A new shell session will parse the updated configuration file and will have the new `$JAVA_HOME` value.

This assumes that the terminal starts new shells as login shells.  If it doesn't, the change should go into `~/.bashrc`.  If you're not using `bash` but some other shell, the filename will depend on what shell you're using.

To change the value of `$JAVA_HOME` in an existing session, you will have to set the value explicitly on the command line, or, as you discovered, source the shell initialization file (which may or may not have other side effects depending on what the other commands in the file are doing).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
export JAVA_HOME ~ Blah
```

on your bash_profile or zshrc, use

```
export PATH = <YOUR FULL LOCATION JDK>/bin:$PATH
```

Now anytime it will work. You have to add `bin`.