# it does not work the creation of environment variable permanent using a script.sh in linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, debian, environment-variables

I am using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash


case "$1" in

  start)
    echo "Iniciando servicio"




   export http_proxy=socks5://192.168.1.2:9090

   export https_proxy     <----I don't want it exported



    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Deteniendo servicio"

    ;;
  *)
   echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

but when executing it and by `env` I don't get the variable that I created :(

```
root@:~# /etc/init.d/a start
Iniciando servicio
root@:~# env
SHELL=/bin/bash
NO_AT_BRIDGE=1
PWD=/root
LOGNAME=root
LS_OPTIONS=--color=auto
HOME=/root
TERM=xterm
USER=root
SHLVL=1
SSH_CLIENT=
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MAIL=/var/mail/root
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
TEXTDOMAIN=Linux-PAM
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I tried running the script with source but it doesn't work because I want to export a single variable not all

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456818/why-does-sourcing-a-script-in-profile-not-work

Comment: it doesn't work that answer doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

When you execute a script, it starts a new bash process. When the script ends, that process closes, taking the environment variable with it.

You need to `source` the script instead of executing it:

```bsh
source /etc/init.d/a start
```

Also, you don't get any output from the `export` command so this

```bsh
   export http_proxy=socks5://192.168.1.2:9090 >> ~/.bashrc
```

does not add anything to the .bashrc.

Comment: it works but another way to do it without having to execute the command with source ???

Comment: No. This is fundamental to the security of Unix : a child process cannot alter the environment of the parent.

Comment: and if I had another variable for example export http = 1 as I would do so that that one did not export that specific one because with source all exports are exported