# How to execute a function in the .profile file

Tags: bash, profile

I have a function which is supposed to remove duplicate copies of directories from my `PATH` environment variable. I have created some duplicates so I can test it but I don't know how to:

1) put the script in the `$HOME/.bashrc` file

Answer (score 1):

Just edit the `.bashrc` file (better make a copy of the original first, just in case) and simply add a line the name of the script you want to execute to the file (at the bottom of the `.bashrc` would be fine).

If the script is not in your home directory, be sure to specify the complete path.

Comment: i am new to linux i don't know how to edit the bashrc file yet or to do what you said, can you please walk me through the steps

Comment: @JohnnyWilliem You have to be a bit more specific - what part makes no sense?

Comment: 1)how to i edit the bashrc file, my friend told me this is where i need to put the script he gave me for it to run

Comment: @JohnnyWilliem Editing the file means you need to open the file (just like you would open a regular text file on the computer) and make changes to it. In this case add a new line to call your script (or add your function). If you aren't comfortable with basic editing of files, perhaps you might want to ask someone with a bit more experience to lend you a hand until you are more used to Linux.

Comment: Yes every piece of information on the net says open a text editor and acces the .profile or .bashrc from there, there is no such file visible in my text editor i am using gedit. I have actually just found the bashrc but cannot find the .profile

Comment: @JohnnyWilliem - don't worry that you can't find `.profile` - it just means it hasn't been created yet, and that's absolutely fine. If you need to create it, go right ahead and use gedit's tools to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The right file for environment variables such as `PATH` is not `~/.bashrc` but `~/.profile`. `.bashrc` is a configuration file for interactive shells; `.profile` is the session startup script. See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085).

Bash is a bit peculiar with its startup files: in login shells, it reads `~/.bash_profile` if it exists and `~/.profile` otherwise. In interactive non-login shells, it reads `~/.bashrc`. There's no reason not to load interactive settings in interactive login shells, and there are many setups where the session start shell is not invoked as a login shell but `~/.profile` is read explicitly. So make your `~/.bash_profile` contain just these two lines:

```
. ~/.profile
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

If you had things in `~/.bash_profile`, move them to `~/.profile` if they are things like environment variable settings, and to `~/.bashrc` if they are interactive shell configuration such as aliases and key bindings.
Put all your `PATH` manipulation in `~/.profile`.