# Adding a folder of jar files to my path

Tags: path, java

I have java tools that I need to use. The tools are in a folder full of jar files. I wanted to add this folder to my path, for the obvious reasons, but after I edit my .bash_profile to include the new folder in the $PATH variable, and source it, it doesn't work. I also tried logging out, and logging back in, and that didn't work either. I just keep getting the error message "Unable to access jarfile .jar"

Comment: Have you checked if it's not a permissions issue?

Comment: You'll have to excuse my ignorance, but how could I check this?

Comment: You may want to check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5569591/unable-to-access-jarfile-in-linux-land

Answer (score 5):

For JAR files, you have to set the CLASSPATH and not the PATH environment variable.

If you're using BASH, it is: `export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:<full_path_to_each_jar_files>"`

You better add it in the file `.bashrc` unless you know what you are doing.

Example:

```
export CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$HOME/java/lib/foebar.jar:$HOME/extra/lib/another.jar"
```

But of course, if you are still invoking the jar file with the Main class you have to use the full path for it:

```
java -jar $HOME/java/lib/main-prog.jar
```

However, you can set its execution right and run it:

```
chmod u+x $HOME/java/lib/main-prog.jar
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/java/lib
main-prog.jar
```

But you have to take care that your classpath is correct and list all required jar.

Comment: I tried export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:<my_new_path>, with the <my_new_path> replaced with the actual path of the folder, sourced and still the same result.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, it's not the path but the .jar file with full path you put, I'll update the answer

Comment: Does this mean I will have to add to the CLASSPATH, a new entry for every jar file. There are about 80 of these jar files.

Comment: @DavyKavanagh Note: do not add the environment variable to `.bashrc`, add it to `.profile`. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/3085#3085)

Comment: @DavyKavanagh sorry for the long delay in the response. But yes, this would mean adding the 80 jar files to the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

If your tools are scripts, which contain commands like

```
 java -jar somejafile.jar
```

then you should edit them to contain the correct path

```
 java -jar /full/path/to/somefile.jar
```

Comment: No, sorry, the tools are the jar files themselves