# .profile in SCO

Tags: path, profile, sco

Where can I find the `.profile` in my user's logon in SCO?

I am needing to edit it, so I can add a `PATH` to it, so that my `PATH` loads up in start up.

I have to add:

```
echo $PATH
```

... as I have already edited the `PATH`.

Any help on where to find this `.profile` file would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Bahamat: Thanks for the edit. It makes more sense that way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.profile`, like any “dot file” (configuration file whose name begins with a `.`), is located in your home directory. This is the default directory when you log in, you can use the `cd` command with no argument to return there, and you can use `~` as a shortcut to it, e.g. you can refer to your `.profile` as `~/.profile` no matter what the current directory is.

If your `.profile` is absent, the system behaves as if it was empty (this is the case for most dot files). So if you want to add something, create the file if necessary. Use the text editor of your choice.

Adding `echo $PATH` to `.profile` is useless, and even a bad idea because it can break remote file copying tools such as `rsync`. I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to add a directory to your `PATH`, put this in your `~/.profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/some/extra/directory
```

This adds the specified directory last in the search path. Or if you want to add the subdirectory `bin` from your home directory to the front of the search path:

```
PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Some antique shells require an additional line `export PATH`, but I think even on SCO it isn't necessary this millennium.

Comment: Thank you for that. I recently installed GCC on this SCO machine, and it still won't work, as it can't find the `lib` files. So I thought I'd add the file path to the `$PATH`. This is the PATH that I put in: `/opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/`

Comment: @Kevdog777 This directory doesn't look like something that should be in any search path. Also, if something can't find a library, you may need to add a directory to the library search path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and not to the executable search path `PATH`. If you need more help, copy-paste the error message.

Comment: Sorry for being dof, but where can I find `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? I just tried `cd ~/LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and it said: `bash: cd: /u/test/LD_LIBRARY_PATH: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Kevdog777 That's an environment variable, like `PATH`. You might add a line like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local/lib` to your `.profile`. Note that I can't be sure this would solve your problem without seeing the exact error message.

Comment: There is not necessarily an error message. Just when I am compiling a script, I get the following files are not found. `In file included from test.c:76:
strutil.c:2: string.h: No such file or directory
strutil.c:3: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from test.c:77:
pcutils.h:3: ctype.h: No such file or directory
In file included from test.c:78:
pcutils.c:2: string.h: No such file or directory
pcutils.c:3: stdio.h: No such file or directory
test.c:79: time.h: No such file or directory
test.c:81: stdio.h: No such file or directory` - I will try add the export path now.

Comment: Sorry Gilles, I actually have added the `$PATH` to `.bashrc` - `.profile` has the following text: `bash - echo $PATH`

Comment: I have added this to my `.bashrc` file: `GCCPATH=/opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local
PATH=$PATH:$GCCPATH/bin:$GCCPATH/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2`
So you say I should add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local/lib` to the `.profile` file instead of this `.bashrc`?

Comment: @Kevdog777 First, set environment variables in `.profile`, not in `.bashrc`. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085 For your compilation issue, you need to pass `-I` options to the compiler; you can use `make CFLAGS='-I /opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local/include'` (or whatever the directory containing the headers is), but this should be normally done by setting the right options when compiling gcc. If you still have trouble compiling programs, I suggest that you ask a new question, and be sure to restate all the facts.

Comment: I have started a new question now [Unable to find headers in GCC](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43763/unable-to-find-headers-in-gcc). I have managed to find those headers, but there is one remaining that I am battling to find.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create the .profile file using the user's login and then I had to add:

```
echo $PATH
```

And then I logged off and back on, and it saved it correctly.