# Unable to find headers in GCC

Tags: compiling, gcc, sco, header-file

I am trying to compile a program using GCC in SCO, and I am unable to find the `ctype.h` file. I have managed to find the other files that were missing when compiling, like `string.h` etc.

I was getting this returned **before** I found where most of the other files were:

```
In file included from test.c:76:
strutil.c:2: string.h: No such file or directory
strutil.c:3: stdio.h: No such file or directory
In file included from test.c:77:
pcutils.h:3: ctype.h: No such file or directory
In file included from test.c:78:
pcutils.c:2: string.h: No such file or directory
pcutils.c:3: stdio.h: No such file or directory
test.c:79: time.h: No such file or directory
test.c:81: stdio.h: No such file or directory
```

Most of those files are in `/opt/K/SKUNK99/Gcc/2.95.2pl1/usr/local/lib/gcc-lib/i386-pc-sco3.2v5.0.5/2.95.2/include/oldstyle`

**Now it is showing this:**

```
In file included from test.c:77:
pcutils.h:3: ctype.h: No such file or directory
```

**Therefore my question is:**

- Where can I find the `ctype.h` file?

This question is related to [.profile in SCO](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43382/profile-in-sco/43442#43442)

Comment: `ctype.h` is part of the C standard library. You should get that by default. I don't know what OS you're on, but make a search for `glibc`.

Comment: I'm using SCO Opensever 5.0.7

Comment: OK, don't know anything about that, sorry.

Comment: How did you install GCC? This looks like the Skunkware distribution, did you follow the [official instructions](http://www.sco.com/skunkware/devtools/index.html#gcc)? In particular, did you install the system libraries and headers as indicated?

Comment: @Gilles: I installed it using those instructions and also asked a question on this site [Install Compiler GCC in SCO](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43177/install-compiler-gcc-in-sco). I followed the instruction that hhaamu gave me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctype.h` is part of the standard C library, so it really should be on your system somewhere. I don't use SCO, but on my various FreeBSD machines at home, and the numerous Solaris machines here at work, `ctype.h` is in `/usr/include`. If it's not there on your SCO machine, perhaps it's in `/usr/local/include`? Or perhaps there's some other standard location under SCO. `find` should be able to tell you where it is, in any case.

Comment: It's more complicated than that. On some “exotic” platforms, and I suspect (but I don't know) that SCO is exotic, GCC uses a modified version of the system headers. The installation process should have generated these headers and set the default include path to include their location though.