# gvim pipes not reading zshrc when started from desktop

Tags: vim, vimrc, zsh

I'm using `zsh` as my default shell and using `.zshrc` to modify my environment variables. When I start `gvim` from terminal everything is fine however if I start gvim with the desktop icon, my env variables are gone. (Just to clear it out, `:shell` is fine but `:!` commands are not)

I have tried to move my environment variables to `.zprofile` but it didn't work. If I move them to `.profile` it works but then again I need to duplicate my variables as `zsh` does not read `.profile`

I don't know much about the internal handling of shells in `gvim`. Is it possible read `.zshrc` or `.zprofile` for `:!` commands?

**Note:** I'm using an `ubuntu` system. Any elegant solution involving the OS are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not an interactive or a login shell I think you're left with using `~/.zshenv`. The following is from section "STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES" in `zshall(1)`:

```
Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  If the shell is a login
shell,  commands  are  read  from  /etc/zsh/zprofile  and  then $ZDOT-
DIR/.zprofile.  Then, if the shell is interactive, commands  are  read
from  /etc/zsh/zshrc  and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc. Finally, if the shell
is a login shell, /etc/zsh/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.
```

Comment: used `.zshenv`, relogged and it's working, thanks..

Answer (score 6):

> using `.zshrc` to modify my environment variables

That's the root cause of your problem. `.zshrc` is a startup file for interactive shell sessions. Use it to set shell settings, not to set environment variables. Environment variables are typically set in a session file such as `.profile`. See [Alternative to .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085) (what goes for `.bashrc` also goes for `.zshrc`).

If zsh is your login shell, it doesn't read `~/.profile`, but it reads `~/.zprofile`. Note that zsh doesn't have to be your login shell even if it's your interactive shell: you can use `/bin/sh` as your login shell and set `SHELL=$(command -v zsh)` in your environment so that terminal emulators and the like run zsh. Since you say that defining your environment variables in `~/.zprofile` didn't work, this is probably how your system is already set up, but it's hard to tell without information more precise that “didn't work”.

If your login shell is zsh, put the following line in your `~/.zprofile` to read `.profile`:

```
emulate ksh -c '. ~/.profile'
```

You can usually get away with a plain `. ~/.profile`, because the incompatibilities between zsh and Bourne-style shells are unlikely to come up in a `.profile`.

Comment: well I had set my shell using `chsh` so I guess zsh is my login shell as well as the one showing up in `$SHELL`. "didn't work" meaning effects are not visible when using `:!` commands (I did not forget to relog as well). putting `. ~/.profile` alike in `.zprofile` doesn't solve the problem either because the problem is it does not read that file at all. Anyway Thor's answer is working, thanks..