# Global bash_profile

Tags: bash, osx, profile, bashrc, etc

I realize there are `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc` files for setting global environment variables and maybe I'm just misunderstanding their purposes, but...

Is there a global `bash_profile` file?

I'm using Mac OS X

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not called `bash_profile`, but the standard place for global bash configuration is `/etc/bash.bashrc`. It's usual to call this from `/etc/profile` if the shell is bash. For example, in my `/etc/profile` I have:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1=’0
    if [ ‐f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  fi
fi
```

In terms of usage, `/etc/profile` provides system-wide configuration for all Bourne compatible shells (sh, bash, ksh, etc.). There's normally no need for an equivalent `/etc/bash_profile`, because the intention of the profile file is to control behaviour for login shells. Normally anything you want to do there is not going to be bash-specific. `/etc/bash.bashrc` is bash-specific, and will be run for both login and non-login shells.

To further complicate things, it looks like OS X doesn't even have an `/etc/bash.bashrc`. This is probably related to the fact that Terminals in OS X [default to running as login shells](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html), so the distinction is lost:

> An exception to the terminal window guidelines is Mac OS X’s
>   Terminal.app, which runs a login shell by default for each new
>   terminal window, calling .bash_profile instead of .bashrc. Other GUI
>   terminal emulators may do the same, but most tend not to.

I don't run OS X, so the extent of my knowledge ends there.

Comment: Don't read `/etc/bash.bashrc` from a non-interactive shell. `/etc/profile` can be read by non-interactive shell. See [Difference between Login Shell and Non-Login Shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38175)

Comment: @Gilles - I'm not clear what point you're trying to make here. A non-interactive login shell is an unusual thing indeed. For reference, the code I quote isn't my own creation. It's from the default `/etc/profile` in Ubuntu 12.04. What would you suggest instead if one wanted an `/etc/profile` which was executed only under bash, and no other sh-compatible shell?

Comment: The system `/etc/profile` file for my system contains a comment at the top that reads: `# System-wide .profile for sh(1)`. Does this mean `profile` is `sh` specific? Does `sh` somehow run before `bash`?

Comment: @Josh Voigts - `sh` is a subset of `bash`. `/etc/profile` is executed for `sh`, `bash`, and all other Bourne-compatible shells.

Comment: @ire_and_curses It appears the file is called `/etc/bashrc` on the mac, not `/etc/bash.bashrc`. It also appears to run for `/bin/sh` as well.

Comment: @ire_and_curses ... and *others* -- Non-interactive scripts and login-s probably make up at least 60% of production apps.  Some *easy* examples would be services like: HTTPD, *database*(s), queue managers, email, networking, almost all cron jobs, *middleware* of all religions ...  Apply the 80:20 rule.  The interactive applications normally represent the **20%** and so called, *non*-Interactive programs, scripts libraries, and entry-points will fall into the 80% bucket.  I'm not just asserting this -- Check.  Run **Htop** on your server or PC... *btw*: in the olde-days, t'was more like 90:10%.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/profile` is the global `bash_profile`. There's no file that's specific to bash, bash just reads the standard file read by all Bourne-style shell. That's where you can set system-wide environment variables.

See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085) for a generic overview of bash's common startup files.

Answer (score 2):

## Setup Interactive Shell (Bash) Globally

This does not load `/etc/profile`, so nothing in `/etc/profile.d/` gets loaded (unlike login shells, see the end).

The global file for this is /etc/bashrc or /etc/bash.bashrc (depending on `-DSYS_BASHRC=` flag set at compile time):

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"
```

Usually it is a good idea to leave this file as-is (as much as possible) to avoid conflicts. The strategy I use is similar to the one that login (/etc/profile) shells use.

My strategy is to append a loader to the above file:

```
# Add new directory analog to /etc/profile.d
mkdir /etc/bashrc.d

# Write the loader to /etc/bash.bashrc (it might be /etc/bashrc on as mentioned above)
cat >> /etc/bash.bashrc << 'EOF'
# I appended this: Load scripts from /etc/bashrc.d
if test -d /etc/bashrc.d; then
  for script in /etc/bashrc.d/*.sh; do
    test -r "$script" && . "$script"
  done
  unset item
fi
EOF
```

Now I can easily add n customizations to the global interactive (bash) shell file by putting new .shfiles into the /etc/bashrc.d directory.

### Colorize Grep Globally

/etc/bashrc.d/grep.sh

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

You can do this with this one-liner:

```
printf "alias grep=\'grep --color=auto\'" > /etc/bashrc.d/grep.sh
```

### Compare profile.d vs bashrc.d

If, after reading this, you remain unconvinced, do this to convince yourself:

```
printf "alias grep=\'grep --color=auto\'" > /etc/profile.d/grep.sh
```

Open a new terminal emulator and search for some common word in your user directory like "the" using grep

```
grep -r 'the'
```

Nothing should be colored. Do the same thing in a virtual console by doing CTRLALTF1 (remember that your X server is probably running at CTRLALTF7 so that you can switch back. If your forget, just restart your desktop manager, for example)

```
grep -r 'the'
```

will yield colored results as desired.

Nothing should be colored. Do the same thing in a virtual console by doing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (remember that your X server is probably running at <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd> so that you can switch back. If your forget, just restart your desktop manager, for example)

```
grep -r 'the'
```

will yield colored results as desired.

A login shell is what you get when you boot a machine or switch virtual consoles with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> through <kbd>FNth</kbd> virtual console.

A Login Shell loads `/etc/profile` while loads `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` files.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may set the variable in your local .bashrc file using the keyword "export"; for example:
export HI='Hello_World'