# $PATH in /etc/profile not inherited by user shell

Tags: terminal, environment-variables, login, profile, gdm

I have this in `/etc/profile` in Fedora 17:

```
PATH=$PATH:"/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin"
EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs -nw"
PSQL_EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs"
PAGER="/usr/bin/less"

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL EDITOR PSQL_EDITOR PAGER
```

The $PATH variable concatenation is in effect when I login as `root` or as `postgres` but not when I login to my account. I'm using terminator.

As root:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:/root/bin
```

As postgres:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin:/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin
```

In my account:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/cpn/.local/bin:/home/cpn/bin
```

Notice the absence of the `/usr/pgsql-9.2/bin` path.

`/home/cpn/.bash_profile` has this line:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH
```

When I `su -` (notice the `-`) to my account the path is there so I guess it is a matter of `login` vs `not login` shell.

How to make the terminal to always open a login shell?

Comment: Most, but not all, login methods read `/etc/profile`. How do you log in? If you use a graphical display manager (a program where you type your password in graphics mode), which one (e.g. gdm, kdm, lightdm, …)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Terminator. Edited the question to add it.

Comment: Terminator is a terminal emulator in which you can run a shell. How do you log in (i.e. where do you type your username and password)?

Comment: @Gilles I login to Cinnamon. I guess it uses gdm.

Comment: @Clodoaldo If you need to have the path set, why not try to simply include `. /etc/profile` as the first line of your `.bash_profile`?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the directory in your `PATH` for *all* sessions, you could add it to `/etc/environment`. Be careful if you do that though - if you screw up the `PATH` in `/etc/environment` there's a chance that your system will not boot anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the correct fix. I did check `Run command as a login shell` in terminator -> profiles -> Command.

Comment: No, that's not a good idea. See [Alternative to .bashrc](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

Comment: As Gilles noted, there's a difference between login and non-login shells, so that non-login ones do not load /etc/profile by default, as described here: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/postlfs/profile.html. So it seems to depend on gdm (if it's still gdm), whether it sources "/etc/profile" or not. Try reading /etc/gdm/Xsession, it might not contains the source strings, as in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/794315