# How to automatically mount remote directories on login / startup

Tags: remote, automounting, sshfs

Everytime I boot, I use `sshfs` to mount remote directories. I am thinking to put these short commands in my .bashrc, but that does not seem to be The Right Way™.

What is the proper way to run `sshfs` on login?

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, [`.bashrc` isn't right](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc). That file is read when you open a terminal running an interactive shell (if your shell is bash).

You can perform sshfs mounts at boot time, but that only works if you don't need any interactive authentication: in most setups this means a passwordless key. (There are other ways, but they only apply inside trusted networks where you would typically already have something like NFS.)

- If you're root, you can add an entry in [`/etc/fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab). Note that this will use root's `~/.ssh` to look up keys and known hosts.

  ```
  example.com:/remote/path /mount/point fuse.sshfs idmap=user,uid=1234
  ```
- You can put an `@reboot` [crontab entry](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).

  ```
  @reboot sshfs -o idmap=user example.com:/remote/path /mount/point
  ```

If you need to type a password to send to the remote server, you need to log in and have a user interface available first. Same thing if you need to type a password to unlock a key.

Most window managers and desktop environments allow you to run custom commands when you log in. You can run a snippet like the following (assuming your environment already starts an SSH agent — most do these days):

```
SSH_ASKPASS=ssh-askpass ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
mount | grep ' /mount/point ' ||
sshfs -o idmap=user example.com:/remote/path /mount/point
```

`mount | grep ' /mount/point ' ||` checks whether the filesystem appears to be mounted already, in case you log in through multiple means.
Alternatively, without using an agent:

```
mount | grep ' /mount/point ' ||
SSH_ASKPASS=ssh-askpass sshfs -o idmap=user example.com:/remote/path /mount/point
```

If you don't have the `ssh-askpass` program, another method is to open a terminal just to do the mounting:

```
xterm -e 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa'
mount | grep ' /mount/point ' ||
sshfs -o idmap=user example.com:/remote/path /mount/point
```

For a text mode log in, put `ssh-add` in your `~/.profile`. Run it only if the shell is interactive.

```
case $- in
  *i*)
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    ;;
esac
sshfs -o idmap=user example.com:/remote/path /mount/point
```

Comment: We have some issues where this mount (from `.bash_profile`) will not work if the user logs in shortly after boot - the network (wifi) isn't up yet. A possible solution might be running a script on network up.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mount file systems at boot, you need to put them into your `/etc/fstab`. Here is an example from OpenBSD documentation. I do this regularly for NFS storage on remote servers.

```
10.0.0.1:/work /mnt nfs rw 0 0
```

That format will work well. Your IP then the directory you want to mount. And then where you want to mount it on the remote server. `fstab` is the best way to do it at mount. Or you can have a little script you can execute when you boot up.

Comment: This wouldn't work as written for per-user fuse mounts like sshfs.

Answer (score 0):

For this use-case, I comfortably use [afuse, a `FUSE`-based sshfs auto-mounter<sup>[1]</sup>](https://github.com/pcarrier/afuse).

On distros with [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) you can easily use an `afuse`user service unit file [like the one posted in another question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528699/127903).

You can also (re-)spawn [afuse](/questions/tagged/afuse) by a [few simple lines of shell-script<sup>[2]</sup>](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294965/127903) sourced from [`~/.profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3052/127903).

[1]: `afuse` is available in the package manager for most distros of Linux.

[2]: This linked script is from my [question about turning this setup into a `systemd` user service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294965/127903).