# Integration of afuse user-level automounter with sshfs as a systemd service spawned from login for local users

Tags: linux, scripting, systemd, automounting, sshfs

Edit 2020: I've been using the [systemd-answer posted below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528699/127903) for several years now, and am quite happy with it.

To facilitate working with remote files, I setup [`afuse`](https://github.com/pcarrier/afuse) with [`sshfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to run from `.bashrc` of local users. It works, after bash init all remote trees from `~/.ssh/config/` are mounted on-demand under `~/scp/`, with correct access rights/restrictions.

This is currently in (a file, that is sourced from) `.bashrc`:

```bsh
exists(){ [[ ${1:0:1} == "/" ]] && { test -f $1 || test -d $1; } \
          || command -v $1 >/dev/null 2>&1;                        }

# Run an afuse process as daemon
if pgrep -u $USER -f "afuse.*$USER/scp" >/dev/null ; then
  echo "afuse/sshfs already running"
else
  exists afuse && exists sshfs && exists $HOME/scp \
  && export TAfuseX=$(mktemp --suffix=__afuse) && chmod u+x "$TAfuseX" \
  && echo -e "#!/bin/sh\ngrep '^Host ..' ~/.ssh/co* |colrm 1 5" > $TAfuseX \
  && echo "running afuse/sshfs with nohup" \
  && nohup afuse -o mount_template="sshfs %r:/ %m" \
                 -o unmount_template="fusermount -u -z %m" \
                 -o populate_root_command=$TAfuseX \
                 ~/scp 2>&1 > ~/afuse.log
fi
```

(The above already incorporates a helpful hint from @sato-katsura)

The above makes sure, it normally runs until machine-shutdown. It is independent of X stops/starts. In case of afuse crash (has never been observed by me), the next shell re-spawns it.

Do you see any useful optimizations, pitfalls, or have other hints, even before migrating this to `systemd`? How would you wrap that into a systemd user unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) user service unit definition file for a few years now: `afuse.service`

```bsh
[Unit]
Description="SSHFS via Afuse automounter"
AssertPathExists=%h/scp/
AssertFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/afuse
AssertFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/sshfs

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=%h/scp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/afuse \
    -o fsname=AutoSCP \
    -o timeout=300 \
    -o auto_unmount \
    -o flushwrites \
    -o mount_template="sshfs -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o reconnect %%r:/ %%m" \
    -o unmount_template="fusermount -u -z %%m" .
Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true
#NoNewPrivileges=true  <- That option breaks this unit, why?

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Create the file `afuse.service` with above contents in:

- `~/.config/systemd/user/` if installing only for you
- `/etc/systemd/user/` if installing for all local users

Install this service with:

```bsh
mkdir ~/scp  # Or Home Directories of all existing users + /etc/skel/ 
systemctl --user daemon-reload   # If root, then omit '--user'
# If enabling only for the current user:
systemctl --user enable afuse.service
# If enabling for all users, execute as root:
# systemctl --user --global enable service
systemctl --user start afuse.service
```

If needed, you can configure your SSH-AGENT to place the socket not in `/tmp/...`, but somewhere under `~`, then this service ought to be able to use the agent. (If there is demand, I could add exact steps for that too, @dirdi)

Comment: I really like this approach, but could not make it work together with the ssh-agent. Thus it does not work if the ssh key file is protected by a passphrase. Maybe you can extend the answer to cover this case, too.