# How to auto mount an ssh file system on demand with an RSA key

Tags: ssh, automounting, key-authentication, sshfs

I am trying to auto mount a folder from my raspberry pi (`/home/pi/server_folder`), to a local folder (`/home/my_name/raspberrypi`).  I can do this with sshfs (auto mount in fstab) when I set up a blank rsa key, but when I try to use an actual key, like 123, the raspberry pi filesystem wont mount.  This is pretty obvious, since I have to supply the passphrase, but is there a way to have it ask for the passphrase when I first try to access `/home/my_name/raspberrypi`, or do something similar to that? Because if someone gets my laptop, they dont need to put a password or anything in to get access to my raspberry pi, if I leave the rsa key blank.  I have looked into `autofs`, and `autosshfs`, but autosshfs won't download, and autofs doesn't explain how to mount with an actual rsa key (well, I haven't found a guide on how to).  I'm using arch Linux, latest version.  Here is the fstab entry:

```
pi@10.0.0.50:/home/pi/server_folder/ /home/my_name/raspberrypi  fuse.sshfs noauto,x-systemd.automount,_netdev,users,idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/my_name/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,reconnect 0 0
```

which is what arch wiki says to do (but doesn't explain very well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since SSHFS is based on FUSE, it's easier to use a non-root automounter. Use [afuse](http://afuse.sourceforge.net/), that's prety much what it was designed for. One-time setup:

```
mkdir ~/.afuse
ln -s .afuse/raspberrypi/server_folder ~/raspberrypi
```

To start the automounter:

```
afuse -o mount_template="sshfs %r:/ %m" -o unmount_template="fusermount -u -z %m" ~/.afuse
```

Make sure that the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` variable is set when you start `afuse`, i.e. it must be started after `ssh-agent`. Run `ssh-add` to load the key into the SSH agent, and then you'll be able to access the SSHFS directories.

Comment: Is there any way to get it to work after a shutdown?

Comment: @Vityou Put the `afuse` invocation in your session startup scripts (e.g. `.profile`, `.config/autostart`, …).

Comment: afuse hasn't been updated in 7 years

Comment: @crypdick It's still in major distributions such as Debian. Is there any reason not to use it?

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Gilles' correct answer, and to address some further thoughts addressed in comments to his answer regarding 'Integration of [afuse](/questions/tagged/afuse) into (profile) startup (scripts)':

You can enable on-demand [sshfs](/questions/tagged/sshfs) mounting by [adding a script invocation to your e.g. `~/.profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/294965/127903) or [create a user level systemd service unit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528699/127903).

I favor the [systemd](/questions/tagged/systemd) [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528699/127903): `~/.config/systemd/user/afuse.service`

```
[Unit]
Description="SSHFS via Afuse automounter"
AssertPathExists=%h/scp/
AssertFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/afuse
AssertFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/sshfs

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=%h/scp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/afuse \
    -o mount_template="sshfs -o ServerAliveInterval=10 -o reconnect %%r:/ %%m" \
    -o unmount_template="fusermount -u -z %%m" .
Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true
#NoNewPrivileges=true
#Environment=

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```