# Mounting remote USB drive to laptop via FTP on Debian 12

Tags: debian, mount, ftp

Initial data: USB flash drive 32GB (EXT4) mounted on router D-Link DIR-825.

On router setup page I enabled FTP server, set port, directory and created user with `password`.

Laptop on Debian 12 (with XFCE).

I checked access to USB flash drive from laptop via FileZilla. It worked.

Question: What should I do in order for the USB flash drive mount automatically to my laptop on starting up the OS so I can use it.

My solution: If I understood it correctly, it should be specified in the file `/etc/fstab`, but I haven't yet figured out how.

Comment: While you could try to use something like `curlftps`, I'd suggest using `ssh` if available, something like this: [How to auto mount an ssh file system on demand with an RSA key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307878/how-to-auto-mount-an-ssh-file-system-on-demand-with-an-rsa-key)

Comment: You can try setting up `ftp` with `rclone`[0]. `rclone` can mount `ftp` as filesystem using `fuse`. [0]https://rclone.org/ftp/, [1] https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_mount/.