# Proper place to put shell prompt(PS1) when use sh/bash/zsh together

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, prompt, dash

I'm using dash(sh) or bash or zsh. If possible, I would prefer to put in common place.

I want to put proper PS1 settings when I interactive with shell, so these situation should be considered

1. login (show PS1)
2. su
3. sudo
4. script (Don't show PS1)

I was put PS1 on .bashrc, but it seems not always workable.

Comment: have you executed your code manually , means without bashrc , is it working ?, if possible post your code.

Answer (score 4):

Each shell has its own escape sequences for `PS1`, so you need to set it separately for each shell. Furthermore, `PS1` only makes sense for interactive shells, it isn't used by other programs. So put `PS1` in the interactive startup file for your shell:

- `~/.bashrc` for bash
- `~/.kshrc` for ksh
- `~/.zshrc` for zsh

Bash has a quirk: it doesn't load `.bashrc` in a login shell, it only loads `~/.bash_profile` or absent this `~/.profile`. To fix this, put the following lines in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

For more information about shell setup files, see [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same prompt for all shells and users, then put it in the `/etc/profile` file. It is sourced by all shells, and is the standard place for defining PS1.

Comment: Or in ~/.profile if it is just one user.

Comment: @Johan - You are right, but `su` specifically indicates it's multiple users.

Comment: I still have problem of setting on /etc/profile, 1. how to separtarte different PS1 on different shell.  2. How to check set PS1 in human interactive only.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is use commonly named vars to define the terminal escapes specific to each shell's interpretation in their own sourced script, then bring it all together at the end in a single prompt:

```
~/.zshrc

    esc1='SPECIFIC TO ZSH'
    esc2='SPECIFIC TO ZSH'
    . ~/.common_prompt

~/.bashrc

    esc1='SPECIFIC TO BASH'
    esc2='SPECIFIC TO BASH'
    . ~/.common_prompt

~/.dashrc

    esc1='SPECIFIC TO DASH'
    esc2='SPECIFIC TO DASH'
    . ~/.common_prompt

~/.common_prompt

     esc3='COMMONLY INTERPRETED ESCAPE SEQUENCE'
     PROMPT_COMMAND='eval PS1=\"printf %b "$esc1" "$esc2" "$esc3"\"'
```

And if one shell is likely to do more with the prompt than another, just `.dot` sourcing `.common_prompt` file doesn't have to be the end. So if `zsh` is going to do more processing than `dash,` for instance - *because it will* - you just take it from there:

```
~/.zshrc

    esc1='SPECIFIC TO ZSH'
    esc2='SPECIFIC TO ZSH'
    . ~/.common_prompt
    _more_processing "${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
```

Comment: Neither dash nor zsh honors `$PROMPT_COMMAND`. zsh has an analogue in `precmd`, but dash has none.