# Is GREP_OPTIONS= --color=always ignored?

Tags: ubuntu, grep, less

I was playing around with setting `GREP_OPTIONS` and couldn't get it to work. Just curious as to why.

Simple test commands output:

```
richard@ubuntu:~$ echo $GREP_OPTIONS

richard@ubuntu:~$ 

richard@ubuntu:~$ ls | grep o 
Desktop
downloads
Dropbox
ebooks
workspace

richard@ubuntu:~$ ls | grep o --color=always | less -R 

richard@ubuntu:~$ export GREP_OPTIONS="--color=always" 
richard@ubuntu:~$ ls | grep o  | less -R
```

1. The 1st grep outputs to the terminal in color (each 'o' is red)
2. The 2nd grep outputs via less in color (same as 1)
3. But the 3rd grep outputs to less but in black & white – but this should be in color.

So it appears that grep is ignoring `GREP_OPTIONS`.  Is that a bug or am I doing something wrong?

(Ubuntu 12.04.2, GNU grep 2.10)

Comment: `grep v3.1` loudly complains about `GREP_OPTIONS` on every invocation: `grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script`

Comment: I use: `alias grep='GREP_COLOR="1;33;40" LANG=C grep --color=auto'` for highlighting in yellow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `grep o` produces color output, then either `grep` is an alias to `grep --color=auto` or `grep --color=always` (or possibly more options), or `GREP_OPTIONS` is set to a value that contains `--color=auto` or `--color=always`. Since `$GREP_OPTIONS` is empty, it must be the alias.

Since `grep o | less -R` doesn't show colors, the alias must be to `grep --color=auto` (a sensible choice). With the alias, the `grep` command always receives the `--color` option on the command line, and this takes precedence over the environment variable.

If you want to use the environment variable, remove the alias definition from your `~/.bashrc`, or for one session run `unalias grep`. You can replace `alias grep='grep --color=auto'` by `export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'`: they have essentially the same meaning, except that:

- setting `GREP_OPTIONS` to a different value only overrides the latter;
- the alias only kicks in when you run `grep` from an interactive shell, whereas setting `GREP_OPTIONS` also applies when `grep` is run from scripts and other applications.

Never put `--color=always` or most other options in `GREP_OPTIONS`: it would break many programs that parse the output of `grep`. `--color=auto` is about the only safe option to put in `GREP_OPTIONS`. For anything else, use the alias. Future versions of GNU grep will drop support for the option for this reason.

Note that the alias definition goes into `~/.bashrc` (it's a shell setting), whereas the environment variable definition goes into `~/.profile` (it's a session setting). See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

If you want to run the unaliased command just once, run `\grep` instead of `grep` (quoting any part of the name bypasses the alias lookup).

Comment: Yes you're right, running \grep ... shows it correctly. Thanks for bonus tip for advising me against using "=always" in .bashrc. +1

Comment: Please note that `GREP_OPTIONS` is deprecated in favor of the `alias` variant.