# How does the path environment variable work in Linux?

Tags: environment-variables, path, session

I'm confused how the PATH environment variable works under Linux. I'm a Linux Mint 15 user.

First, I read about editing the `/home/.bashrc` file and doing a `PATH=$PATH:/directory`,
but I also knew about some path stuff managed in `/etc/bash.bashrc`
and so any software installed in `/usr/local/bin` would be reachable from anywhere in the shell.

How does the path variable work under Linux and where should it be placed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic concept to grasp here is that PATH can be defined in many places. As @demure explains in his answer, `PATH=$PATH:/new/dir` means *add* `/new_dir` to `$PATH`, it will not clear the original `$PATH`.

Now, one reason there are many files is intimately connected with the concept of `login` and `non-login` shells. See [here](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile) for a nice summary. The following is from the bash man page (emphasis mine):

> When  bash  is  invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, **it first  reads and
>   executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. 
>   After reading that file, it  looks  for  ~/.bash_profile, 
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order**, and reads and executes
>   commands from the first one that  exists  and  is readable.   The 
>   --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

When you first log into your system, you start a **login** shell so bash will read the files listed above. Most distributions set a system-wide `$PATH` (which applies to all users) at `/etc/profile` and this is where you should make any changes that you want applied to all users. This is what I have on my Debian:

```
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
```

Once you have logged in, when you open a terminal you start an **interactive, non-login** shell. This is what `man bash` has to say about those:

```
   When  an  interactive shell that is not a login shell
   is started, bash reads  and  executes  commands  from
   /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist.
```

So, those files are read every time you open a new terminal. Your filnal $PATH is the combination of the values in all files. In a typical situation, you log in using a graphical log in manager and start a new session. At this pòint your `$PATH` is whatever was defined in the various `profile` files. If you open a terminal, then you are in an interactive shell and the different `bashrc` files are read which may append things to the `$PATH`.

---

To summarize, all you really need to know is that you can make changes to your user's `$PATH` by editing `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: [No: `.profile`, not `.bashrc`.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

Comment: @Gilles why? If you, for example, switch users with `su`, `~/.profile` is not read while `.bashrc` is. Is it to avoid reloading the $PATH each time you open a new terminal?

Comment: Given that `su` is not supposed to change the environment, that's exactly as designed. If you want the target user's environment, run `su -l`. The most obvious way setting `PATH` in `.bashrc` breaks in common scenarios is that it doesn't take effect in programs started by the window manager.

Comment: @Gilles ah, of course, that makes sense. OK, answer edited, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In your home dir, it would be `.bashrc`, not `.bash.rc`.
The system wide config is `/etc/bashrc` not `/etc/.bash.rc`.

Unix and linux do not use `\some\path\here` file paths, they use `/some/path/here` file paths. `\` is an escape character, and is used to disable other special characters.

You could edit your `$PATH` by adding these to lines to your `~/.bashrc` (`~` means your home dir)

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin:/some/other/path
export PATH
```

Where

- `$PATH` preserves anything already set to the PATH.
- `:` separates entries.
- And the two directories are examples (you don't need the `:/some/other/path` part)

I would not suggest editing your system wide `/etc/bashrc` if you only need changes for yourself.

Comment: [No: `.profile`, not `.bashrc`.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)

Comment: @Gilles while I agree that the ~/.profile is a better choice, not everyone likes to bother with it

Comment: Im new to linux and need to modify my PATH to contain the path for java jdk. Should this be a system wide or user specific change? No one else will be using my laptop either. you say ~/.profile is better to use than .bashrc, which one should a new user that doesnt know much about linux use?

Comment: @Adrian both would affect only the user, `/etc/profile` would be for all users. `~/.bashrc` only affects bash, `~/.profile` affects all* shells. Just use the `~/.profile` if you don't have a preference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the kernel (or initramfs) will supply an initial default PATH value for the `init` process, plus a few other environment variables. You can view them if you want:

```
$ sudo strings /proc/1/environ
selinux=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/
init=/sbin/init
TERM=linux
drop_caps=
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.9.80-atom
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
crashkernel=384M-:128M
PWD=/
rootmnt=/root
```

For daemons and other processes started at boot-up, the `init` process (whether a traditional SysVinit or one of the new replacements like `systemd`) may apply its own default PATH, or just pass through the kernel default value. This may or may not be configurable: see the documentation of your init system.

For login sessions, PAM settings might include `pam_env.so` which could enforce a default PATH for user sessions, configurable in `/etc/security/pam_env.conf`. Or if `pam_env.so` is not used, the process handling the login (e.g. `sshd`, or the traditional `*getty`+`login` pair on the console or serial port logins) might enforce their own default starting PATH for user sessions.

Then, the user's shell will typically execute one or more system-wide login scripts, and one or more user-specific login scripts if they exist. Any of these can add to the existing PATH setting or completely replace it.

Answer (score 0):

for `PATH` i use `/etc/enviroment` and `/etc/login.defs`

...