# How does the unix path get set when the computer first starts?

Tags: linux, osx

I use a mac. If I open a terminal and run `echo $PATH` I get the current "PATH" variable in my environment. If I add something to my path or to my other environment variables, it only persists for as long as that process is alive.

What I want to know is, how did this path get the values it has by default? I looked in my .zshrc (or .bash* if I were using bash) but there's nothing there that exports all programs that are on the path. What is it about the OS the controls this default `PATH` list?

Comment: found a similar inquiry [here][1] hope it clarifies.


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77909/39890

Answer (score 2):

`login(1)` traditionally set `PATH` before turning things over to the shell, though you may need to think differently on OS X, as there's also [`~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html) where such can be set (probably not recommended to use, unless it's necessary for some special application), and last I checked Apple was adding a `path_helper(8)` command to muss with `PATH` in global shell `rc` files under `/etc`.

For ZSH on Mac OS X I disable `path_helper` and set `PATH` manually only in [my `~/.zshenv` file](https://github.com/thrig/dotfiles/blob/master/.zshenv#L13). This may not be ideal if you actually need something under a path set by `path_helper`.

Answer (score 1):

[The link that @corleone posted shows how the $PATH environment variable gets interpreted.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77909/39890)

The reason why it does not persist when you declare it in the terminal is because that is a temporary process that will eventually exit.  The variable has to get set from a file that is sourced when the shell is launched, which will normally be one of your dotfiles.

Unlike many operating systems, OS X does not automatically include a .profile or .bashrc in users' home directories, but instead defaults to .bash_profile, which will be evaluated last if you do create a .profile or .bashrc (which will also be evaluated).

If you want to update your $PATH to include specific directories, the best place to put it (on OS X) would be in your .bash_profile, which will take precedence over any other locations that set that particular variable.  If you don't want to overwrite anything, but just want to add something, in your .bash_profile, you could include a line like this:

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/another/bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `loginwindow.app` is responsible for setting up the initial environment for a user. The `loginwindow.app` passes off the authentication process and when the user is authenticated the environment is setup as if `login -pf USERNAME` is called (read `man login` and `man environ`). At this point the PATH is `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` the same as `user.cs_path = /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` set in the kernel. I should mention that this is all run by root and if you are using a GUI session, there is no shell.

The Terminal.app will start your shell as a login shell by default. `login -pf USERNAME` is run (as root) and then the shell's rc files are read. For `bash` and `ksh`, `/private/etc/profile is read. For`zsh`,`/private/etc/zshenv`is read. For`csh`,`/private/etc/csh.login`is read. All use`/usr/libexec/path_helper `to modify the PATH set by the`loginwindow.app`.

Answer (score 0):

On shell startup, `/etc/profile` runs `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, and the output of that command is `eval`ed to set the initial value of the path. See `man path_helper` to see how this program gets the initial list of directories to put in its output.