# gmrun stopped searching user added path

Tags: environment-variables, run-dialog

gmrun started ignoring the PATH variable I defined in `~/.bashrc` for no obvious reason. Anyone has any idea how I can find out a way to solve this annoying problem?

### EDIT

I have not found the solution, but I ended up switch to [bashrun2](https://code.google.com/p/bashrun2/), which does what I need it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gmrun inherits](https://github.com/rtyler/gmrun/issues/4) the `$PATH` variable set by the parent that spawned it. Hence, you can make it source `~/.bashrc` by initiating it with:

```
bash -ci 'gmrun'
```

This creates an "interactive" shell; this has a few [differences](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html#Interactive-Shell-Behavior) to a non-interactive shell, but works perfectly fine with `gmrun`. Simply bind the command above to your hotkey.

Answer (score 4):

> the PATH variable I defined in ~/.bashrc

There's your problem right there. `.bashrc` is an initialization file for interactive shells. Gmrun doesn't start an interactive shell, it starts the program you tell it to start. So your PATH is never getting set. In fact, in order to get completion in gmrun, you need the PATH environment variable to be set in the environment that you run gmrun in.

Set PATH in the right place: `~/.profile`. This file is read when your session starts. That's where you should define your environment variables.

Don't read `.profile` from `.bashrc` or vice versa. They have completely different purposes and are used in different purposes.

Due to a quirk of bash, `.bashrc` isn't read in an interactive login shell, so you should write a `.bash_profile` that loads the other two for this case:

```
. ~/.profile
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085) and the other posts I cite there for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is an initialization file for **interactive non login** bash instances, I doubt whatever is setup there has ever been taken into account by `gmrun` when not launched from such a shell instance.

If your desktop environment is setup so that any bash initialization file is taken into account, it should be your `.profile` or `.bash_profile` one, and you need to quit and restart your desktop environment before modifications are effective from processes launched by the environment.

Comment: Thanks. But my .profile sources .bashrc, it should be a problem, right?

Comment: @CravingSpirit, I do it only if the shell is interactive (PS1 set) as what I've in my `.bashrc` make sense only for interactive shells (so there is no environment variable definition in my .bashrc, in my experience those who set environment variables definition in their .bashrc are better served by setting the option which make launch shells from their terminal emulator as login shells).

Comment: Testing `PS1` doesn't tell you anything about whether the shell is interactive. I know this is all over the web, I have no idea where it comes from, it's plain wrong. There's a reliable, portable way to determine whether a shell is interactive: test whether `$-` contains `i`.

Comment: @Gilles, one potential source is the bash info manual ;-).  At least in edition 3.2, that is given as an alternative way to testing $-.  I don't remember why I ended up preferring it to testing $- (I traced back my use to 1999 which is the earlier revision I've not lost)