# exported variable disappears when I open a new terminal

Tags: bash, fedora, environment-variables

I type this: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk` so that I can access that directory by typing `cd $JAVA_HOME` but every time I close and open the terminal I have to do this again and again. Is there a way of saving this? I did some research but am not understanding how you could add it to the `bash_profile`.

I'm on the latest Fedora.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add your `export` line in `/your/home/directory/.bashrc`, which is the Bash initialization file sourced when you start an interactive shell.

If you're using the GUI to edit the file, you should note that its name begins with a `.` so it's hidden in the GUI by default. To make it visible, assuming you're using Nautilus, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. If you're using some other file manager, look in its documentation for how you can show hidden files.

Simply edit your `.bashrc` and append your `export` line at its end. This should work when you open and close the terminal and should also be persistent across reboots.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the simple explanation!

Comment: @SiZa I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @SiZa [Define environment variables in `.profile`, not `.bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085)