# $@ and 'set env $PATH' - Why should this statement go into .inputrc?

Tags: bash, zsh, environment-variables

I have a line in my `.zshrc` that says:

```
set env $PATH
```

Apparently this affects the value of `$@`. [I have read](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/339#issuecomment-28161365) that `$@` should be empty and that I should **not** have any `set` statements in my `.zshrc` (at least in Bash some of these statements should actually go in my `.inputrc`file).

Is this valid advice, if so why? What does `set env $PATH` do and why should `$@` be empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misread that comment.

In Bourne-style shells such as bash and zsh, the command [`set`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-set) is a builtin which does two things:

- it sets shell options, e.g. `set -x` turns on the `xtrace` (print debugging traces) option;
- when called with non-option arguments, it sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, …, collectively accessed as `"$@"`).
- As an exception, if the option `-A` or `+A` is passed, `set` assigns to the specified array instead of to the positional parameters.

The command `set env $PATH` sets the positional parameters to a list of two: `env`, and the value of the `PATH` variable. This is not useful.

Calls to `set` with non-option arguments are only useful inside functions and scripts, not in `.zshrc`. While you may have calls to `set` with options, most useful options are set through [`setopt`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-setopt).

`.inputrc` is a configuration file for bash and a few other programs that use the [readline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readline) library. It mainly contains key bindings, and a few option settings of the form `set SETTING VALUE` (but there is no setting called `env`). These options are all related to command line editing. Zsh does not use readline, so `.inputrc` is not relevant to zsh.

I don't know what you were trying to do with the line `set env $PATH`. If you wanted to export PATH to the environment, the syntax is `export PATH`; however:

- `PATH` is already exported, there is no need to call `export` again even if you modify the value (exporting a modified environment variable was only needed in the old Bourne shell).
- You should not modify environment variables in `.zshrc`, as this file is read by all interactive shells. A variable set in `.zshrc` would override anything set by the calling program, and would only affect programs started through that shell. The right place to set your environment variables is in `~/.profile`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.pam_environment`, or other files that are read at the start of your session. See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085) and the linked posts.

If you want to change the path, you need to assign to it:

```
PATH=/completely/new:/value/of/PATH
PATH=/directory/to/add/at/the/beginning:$PATH
PATH=$PATH:/directory/to/add/at/the/end
```

Zsh (like `(t)csh` where it copied it from) provides a variable called [`path`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-path) (all lowercase) which is an array containing the same list of directories as `PATH`. Any update to `PATH` automatically affects `path` and vice versa. So instead of manipulating `PATH`, you can do things like

```
path=(/completely/new /value/of/PATH)
path=(/directory/to/add/at/the/beginning $path)
path+=/directory/to/add/at/the/end
path+=(/one/more /and/another)
```