# PATH update does not stay after reboot

Tags: path

I have updated the PATH environmental variable on a Redhat distribution but after reboot, the path is gone.

To add the path:

```
PATH=/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin
export  PATH  

echo $PATH
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/bin
```

reboot removes the path

echoing after

```
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make changes in environment path persistent, add that lines with `export` to your `.profile` file.

Comment: That does not appear to make a difference - please see my edit

Comment: No, [do not change environment variables in `.bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc). It doesn't work (variables set there won't be defined in programs that aren't started via a terminal). @AndroidAddict Don't accept answers that didn't help you!

Comment: @Gilles better?