# Set Group Environment Path

Tags: rhel, environment-variables

After trying to do a few google searches, I have been unsuccessful on finding a clear answer so I am asking on here. I am looking to how to set an Environment PATH for a group of users and not everyone on the RHEL 6 system as only that group has access to the path?

```
%groupname PATH=$PATH:/usr/groupshare/bin/ #this is a example of my idea but not sure how to make it work
```

*Added Note:* 
You potential duplicate pointed me to a path that helped me find the details on the redhat site. Now I don't want to label the question as a duplicate as the answer isn't exactly the same but I did find an answer. Not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have a bashrc for a usergroup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146599/is-it-possible-to-have-a-bashrc-for-a-usergroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

I found the answer on "[How do I use custom.sh for a global user profile in rhel 6?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/43051)" (requires a redhat account to access) after being pointed to it from the answer of "[Is it possible to have a bashrc for a usergroup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146599/is-it-possible-to-have-a-bashrc-for-a-usergroup)". It says to add a new file to `/etc/profile.d/` to avoid any OS upgrades modifying the /etc/profile back to defaults called <name>.sh and use the information supplied in "[Is it possible to have a bashrc for a usergroup?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146599/is-it-possible-to-have-a-bashrc-for-a-usergroup)" to created the file focused on the group.

This works for RHEL 7 as well. Have not been tested for RHEL 8.

#### Example file details

```
cd /etc/profile.d/
vim groupname.sh
```

#### file contents

> Quoted from the other answer
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> if [ $(id -ng) = 'the_cool_group' ]; then
>      # do stuff for people in the_cool_group
> fi
> case ":$(id -Gn | tr [:space:] :)" in 
>     *:extra_group:*) somecommand;; #tested, works # the user belongs to the group foo
> esac
> ```