# Upstart - load bashrc variable

Tags: bashrc, upstart, env

I'm wondering how to load `bashrc` variables in an upstart script and run (`node.js` in that case server).

What is the best way to do it?

I tried this:

```
exec sudo -u someuser $NODE_PATH $FULL_PATH/$FILE_NAME >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
```

and this

```
exec start-stop-daemon --start -c someuser --exec $NODE_PATH $FULL_PATH/$FILE_NAME >> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1
```

But in the first option the node app can't read the `http_proxy` variable (which is defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc`). In the second one it can't read config files (the node app is installed in the `/opt` folder)

Comment: Can you add what you have tried, please?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, sorry! I tried use sudo with specified user, because I read somewhere that it gives you environment you would have in case of that user

Comment: Would be ok to load whole /etc/bash.bashrc like 'source /etc/bash.bashrc' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force `bash` to read `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` (without the other side effects of using `bash -i`) by tricking it into thinking it's invoked over `ssh`:

```
sudo -Hu someuser env SSH_CLIENT=1 SHLVL=0 \
  "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH" "FULL_PATH=$FULL_PATH" \
  "FILE_NAME=$FILE_NAME" "PROGRAM_NAME=$PROGRAM_NAME" bash -c '
  "$NODE_PATH" "$FULL_PATH/$FILE_NAME" >> "/var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log" 2>&1'
```

`sudo` usually resets the environment, so you need to pass those that way. You want `-H` (or `-i` though `-i` would cause the reading of the profile files) so that `HOME` is set (for the location of `~/.bashrc` at least).

Answer (score 5):

`/etc/bash.bashrc` is read by interactive shells when they start up. It is a place for settings for interactive use, such as completion setup, prompts, etc. Do not set environment variables there. See [Is there a ".bashrc" equivalent file read by all shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc) Good places for system-wide environment variables are [`/etc/environment`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/pam_env.8.html) and `/etc/profile` (and files in `/etc/profile.d`).

The normal [Upstart way to set environment variables](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables) is in the job file itself. Upstart doesn't read `/etc/environment`, but you can load environment variables from a file in the job script:

```
script
. /etc/environment
exec start-stop-daemon …
end script
```

Comment: I like this idea most. It's generally a bad idea to have any additional layers of processes between upstart and the daemon you start. Because who know how this seven-layer salad of sudo, start-stop-daemon, bash, and custom scripts will react to signals, for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can force `bash` to be executed as interactive shell. Try this command:

```
sudo -iu someuser /bin/bash -i -c '$NODE_PATH $FULL_PATH/$FILE_NAME \
>> /var/log/$PROGRAM_NAME.sys.log 2>&1'
```

Now, before your command is executed, `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are sourced by `bash`. It's the same behavior as when you open a terminal.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it seems to doing nothing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1760395, it likely created a file called `/var/log/.sys.log` that contains a complaint about `/ being a  directory` unless those variables are defined in the .bashrc. See the note about environment variables in my answer.