# How to execute source command from sh file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bashrc

I have file called `install.sh` and within this file I write something to `$HOME/.bashrc` file and after that I must call `source` command.
In terminal I can type `source $HOME/.bashrc` but I can't do this in bash script. If I write this to file, then I get following error:

```
./install.sh: 1: ./install.sh: source: not found
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: Is your `#!` line `#!/bin/sh` ? or `#!/bin/bash` ?

Comment: I think that `sh` and `bash` support `.` as a name for `source` eg `. ./install.sh`

Comment: Only `.` is POSIX, so the `source` might be the problem here (if it is not run under `BASH` but rather `SH`).

Comment: In Unix, we do not give executables file-extensions: Consider that you call you script from another script, and then re-write it in python (other languages are available). What should you now call the first script? What happens to the behaviour of the 2nd script?

Comment: @Fiximan your comment does not make sense. I can not determine if you are saying one thing, the opposite, or something else.

Comment: @richard using `.` is POSIX compliant, while `source` is not. So in case he tries to source the file via the `source` command but is doing so with `SH`, he will fail. Did that clarify it?

Comment: @fiximan In english grammar the word before `but` should be followed by a comma (`,`). The phrase before the comma, should may sense on its own: be a valid sentence.

Comment: You should not read `.bashrc` from a script. `.bashrc` is meant to be executed only in interactive environments; it's for setting up terminal parameters, prompts, completion, etc. [Don't set environment variables in `.bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085). [What are you really trying to achieve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to program a bash script, then change your [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (first line of the script file) to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Aaaa what a rookie mistake. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Actually here is a problem. If I say `source $HOME/.bashrc;` in my bash script, then this won't export env variable that I just added to .bashrc file. If I do that in terminal, then it's ok. Any idea why?

Comment: the script runs in its own subshell. Try adding some `echo $var` in the script and  it should be fine, just not exported. (or did you actually `export` the var?)

Comment: In bash script I've added line "export NAME_OF_VAR=/....." to .bashrc and then I want to call source on it. So when I run this script I want to have env variable NAME_OF_VAR set

Comment: @golobich You will have the environment variable set in the script. If you're running the script from the command line, that won't set the variable on the command line. To do that, you'd have to source the script on the command line instead of running it as an external command.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a more simpler way to accomplish what you need, is to use the -f [filename] option provided in bash and load all the environment variable needed from that alternative rc file. The source buliten (built in function) was not meant to function the way you're using it here. The ". , include, and source bulitens were meant to include library (reusable function code) resources into invoked scripts.

> bash -l -f /path_to_file/.foo_rcfile