# 'Chain' shells' profile and runcom files?

Tags: shell, profile, rc

While setting `zsh` up, I found a post stating that to keep a `.zshrc` as clean and backwards compatible as possible, one can 'chain' the shells' configuration files. If I recall, it consists more or less to call `sh`'s in `bash`'s in `zsh`'s so only the shells' exclusive features are set in their respective configuration files. I cannot find the post again, neither on Google nor in my Safari history.
I have extensively read official documentations but it sometimes speaks another language to me.

Is there a way to do this like I write a complete `.profile` which'd be called in `.bash_profile` that'd be called in `.zprofile` ? Same thing for the `.*shrc`, though I am not sure a `.shrc` exists. I know there are different kind of files following the way a shell is started (it could be 'interactive' or not — I don't really know what it consists about) but it's still beyond my knowledge so I'll stick with my user's profile and runcom files for not.

Comment: Why go for the most advanced stuff? Learn POSIX sh, and learn one modern interactive shell. You will have plenty to do. After you master one modern interactive shell, zsh and bash will both do. If you want to get into the guts of the differences of shell implementations you can learn a second. I would not recommend to learn about the idiosyncratic differences for starters. Good luck!

Comment: Answers to http://superuser.com/questions/187639/ suggested this sort of thing, but not for any notion of "cleanliness".

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/44619#44619