# remove an added path from PATH?

Tags: bashrc

in my `~/.bashrc` in Linux , I have a line that adds some paths to `PATH`, something like:

```
PATH=~/mydoc:~/mypython:"$PATH"
```

The purpose of adding `~/mypython` is to use my self-installed python, rather than the system's default one. But now I would like to  change back to use the system's default python. Without logout, is there a simple way to remove `~/mypython` from the value of `PATH`?

Comment: Logout won't do it. When you log in your `~/.bashrc` is automatically executed --- this is how your `PATH` is built in the first place. Just remove `~/mypython` from your `~./bashrc` and execute it: `. ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 5):

```
PATH=$(tr ":" "\n" <<<"$PATH" | grep -Fxv "$HOME/mypython" | paste -sd:)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can update your path in the shell:

```
TRIM=~/mypython
export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e "s,:$TRIM:,:," -e "s,:$TRIM\$,," -e "s,^$TRIM:,," )
```

This is more general than your specific case.  That could be done with

```
TRIM=~/mypython
export PATH=$(echo "$PATH" | sed -e "s,:$TRIM:,:," )
```

I used a temporary variable `TRIM` to store the tilde-expanded value of `~/mypython` because that would not be expanded in the `sed` command.  I also did *not* use `$HOME` because (while it is usually the same) it is not guaranteed to have the same value as the expansion of `~` (tilde).  You can set `HOME` to a different directory from your actual home-directory as needed (not generally a *Good Thing* to do, of course).

For my own use, I use a utility [`newpath`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:newpath), e.g.,

```
export PATH=$(newpath -r ~/mypython)
```

Comment: “`$HOME` is not guaranteed to have the same value as the expansion of `~`” Yes it is. By POSIX, and also in traditional shells. `~` (where expanded) is a shortcut for `$HOME` (always acting as if in double quotes). `$HOME` may not be the user's home directory since anybody can change it, but `~` follows `$HOME`. What could happen here is that `$HOME` at the time of the `PATH` change isn't the same as what it was at the time `PATH` was set, but whether or not it's accessed through `~` doesn't change anything. P.S. why so complicated (and not robust wrt special-character) with sed?

Comment: I used a printing character (comma) to make the example easy to read.  (Regarding tilde vs `HOME`: I apparently have been working with some non-POSIX shells, and forgot to address the chosen audience).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to remove a PATH component which I think handles all edge cases. (Even the evil ones with empty components.)

```
remove_from_PATH () {
  while case $PATH in
          "$1") unset PATH; false;;
          "$1:"*) PATH=${PATH#"$1:"};;
          *":$1") PATH=${PATH%":$1"};;
          *":$1:"*) PATH=${PATH%%":$1:"*}:${PATH#*":$1:"};;
          *) false;;
        esac
  do
    :
  done
}

remove_from_PATH ~/mypython
```

In zsh, it's easier to use the `path` array.

```
path=("${(@)path:#"$HOME/mypython"}")
```

Note that [you shouldn't modify `PATH` in `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085).

Comment: Thanks. WHere should I modify PATH?

Comment: @Tim Click. The. Link.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a function to edit `$PATH` in a line-separated format in your `vi` as if it were a file:

```
pathEdit(){ 
    export PATH="`printf '%s' "$PATH" |tr : '\n'|
    vipe | tr '\n' : |sed 's/:$//'`"; 
}
```

---

If you don't have the `vipe` from `moreutils`, you can emulate it with:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
st=0; tmpf=
tmpf="`mktemp`" && exec 3<>"$tmpf" || st="$?"
rm -f "$tmpf"
[ "$st" = 0 ] || exit "$st"
cat >&3
</dev/tty vi "$@" /dev/fd/3 >/dev/tty
cat /dev/fd/3
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd change your .bashrc and then execute the following:

```
 . .bashrc
```

This takes your .bashrc stuff and places it in your current environment.

Comment: Thanks. How does it remove `~/mypython` from `PATH`?

Comment: EDIT your .bashrc file where the PATH variable is present.

Comment: That won't work since the snippet shown in the question *adds* to `PATH`, it doesn't set it to a fixed value.