# executable wrapper, run original executable from tail of PATH

Tags: zsh, path

There's an executable `/usr/bin/foo` which I and other scripts use, but it misbehaves a bit so I made a Bash wrapper of the same filename in `/usr/local/bin/foo` where I fixed its misbehaviour. My `PATH` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`. In the wrapper script, I have to run the original executable by absolute path in order to not get into an infinite loop:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/foo
#/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/foo | grep -v "^INFO" # reduce output
```

Is there any (Zsh or Bash specific perhaps) straightforward way to execute next `foo` in `PATH`, that is the `foo` that's in `PATH` directories that are after the directory from which current `foo` was executed, so that I wouldn't have to use absolute path to the original executable?

I could make a function for it in `/etc/zshenv` and it's not such a big deal. I'm just wondering if there is anything standard. I don't want to use alias or fix the original executable.

---

EDIT 1:
=
    $ cat /usr/local/bin/foo
    #/bin/zsh
    path=(${path/#%$0:A:h}) foo | grep -v "^INFO" # reduce output

This should empty (but keep) all strings in PATH (`${path/...}`) that fully match (`#%`) the absolute (`:A`) directory (`:h`) of the current executable(`$0`). TBH, I assembled it from StackExchange and don't understand it fully. I hope it's not going to bite me.

## EDIT 2:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/foo
#/bin/zsh
path[${path[(i)$0:A:h]}]=() foo | grep -v "^INFO" # reduce output
```

`$path[(i)foo]` finds the index of `foo` in the array `path` or 1 plus length of the array.

Comment: It *could* bite you if the directory happens to be a substring of some other directory name.  It's probably good enough for personal use, but not for code that you expect others to use.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Could it? From brief testing `${arr[(i)...]}` only considers exact matches, or am I not understanding the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out what directory the script is in (`$0:h` in zsh, `"${0%/*}"` in sh) and remove that directory from `PATH` (`path=(${path:#$0:h})` in zsh, [more complicated in sh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253532/remove-an-added-path-from-path/253760#253760). This could fail if `PATH` contains the same directory twice, e.g. through a symbolic link.

A downside of the straight approach is that this removes the directory from the path, but other programs in the same directory might be desirable. You can solve this issue by doing only the path lookup with a modified path.

```
next=$(path=(${path:#$0:h}); print -lr -- =$0:t)
$next
```

Instead I'd do the `PATH` lookup manually and skip any occurrence of the running script.

```
for d in $path; do
  if [[ -x $d/$0:t && ! $d/$0:t -ef $0 ]]; then
    exec $d/$0:t
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:
 For me `type -a egrep` prints a user-defined alias and the actual `egrep` command, adding yet another `egrep` in my $HOME/bin/ shows it too... In the order; alias first, then the remaining items in the same order as PATH has them.

```
$ cd # go home

$ mkdir -p bin

$ PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH

$ type -a egrep
egrep is aliased to `egrep --color=auto'
egrep is /bin/egrep

$ echo -e >bin/egrep '#!/bin/bash\necho TEST'

$ chmod 755 bin/egrep

$ type -a egrep
egrep is aliased to `egrep --color=auto'
egrep is /home/$USER/bin/egrep
egrep is /bin/egrep

# assuming you're sure it is the only one not in /home and not an alias
$ type -a egrep | grep -Ev '/home|alias' | cut -d' ' -f3
/bin/egrep

$ rm $HOME/bin/egrep
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

# find the other occurrences of a command with the same name in $path that
# are a different file
other_mes=(
  ${^path/#%/.}/$0:t(N*^e['[[ $REPLY -ef $0 ]]'])
)

if (( ! $#other_mes )) {
  print -ru2 Could not find any other $0:t in PATH.
  exit 1
}

# run the first found
$other_mes[1] "$@" | grep -v '^INFO'

# return the exit status of the other me, not of grep
exit $pipestatus[1]
```

- `${path/#%/.}` replaces the empty elements of `$path` with `.`
- `$0:t`: the tail (basename) of `$0`
- `[[ a -ef b ]]` returns true if `a` and `b` are found to be the same file after symlink resolution, either because they are 2 paths to the same file (like `/usr/bin/foo` vs `/bin/foo` because `/bin` happens to be a symlink to `/usr/bin` or `../bin/foo` and `$PWD` is `/usr/local` or `/usr/foo/../bin/foo`, or they are hard links or symlink to each other).

With `sh` syntax (and a `[` implementation that supports `-ef`, most noadays), and assuming `$0` doesn't end in newline characters that could be:

```
#! /bin/sh -
other_me=$(
  me=$(dirname -- "$0")
  IFS=:; set -o noglob
  for dir in $PATH''; do
    other_me=${dir:-.}/$me
    if [ -x "$other_me" ] && [ -f "$other_me" ] && [ ! "$other_me" -ef "$me" ]; then
      printf '%s\n' "$other_me"
      exit
    fi
  done
  printf>&2 '%s\n' "Cound not find any other $me in PATH."
  exit 1
) || exit

{
  exit_status=$(
    {
      {
        "$other_me" "$@" 4>&-
        echo "$?" >&4 4>&-
      } 3>&- | grep -v '^INFO' >&3 3>&- 4>&-
    } 4>&1
  )
} 3>&1
exit "$exit_status"
```

With the convoluted bit at the end to get the exit status of `$other_me`.