# Why does Logic Application not work except directly under sudo?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sudo

I am trying to run [Logic](https://www.saleae.com/downloads) application to talk to my logic analyzer, and I observe the following behavior, after I install the rules under the driver.

```
./Logic 
./Logic: cpp_libs/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

sudo bash
./Logic 
./Logic: cpp_libs/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)

sudo ./Logic 
# Application runs
```

What is the cause for this strange behavior?

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

A plausible explanation for the difference in behavior is that the working and non-working commands are loading different libraries because they have different settings for the library search path `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. There are other environment variables that could matter but are less likely, such as `LD_PRELOAD`, `PATH` (if `./Logic` is a script that depends on some executables — but the error message isn't consistent with that), etc.

A plausible explanation for why invoking the command from an interactive instance of bash doesn't work, but invoking the command directly from `sudo` works, is that you are setting this environment in `.bashrc`, the file that interactive instances of bash runs. Running `sudo` clears almost all environment variables, hence `sudo ./Logic` works; but `sudo bash` followed by `./Logic` doesn't work because running `bash` sets those variables again.

[You should set environment variables in `.profile` (which is executed when the session starts), not in `.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc/3085#3085). Your symptoms are characteristic of one of the problems with changing environment variables in `.bashrc`.

The setting for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should probably not be present in your setup files at all. Adding a directory that shadows system libraries is likely to be a source of incompatibilities. If you need it to run a particular program, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` only when running that program (via a shell wrapper, if you want to automate it), don't set it globally.