# Terminal color usage does not stay

Tags: command-line, ls, colors

I was wondering if any of you knew why doesn't my terminal keep displaying stuff colored, after I use the command `ls -l -a --color=always`
I would like it to stay colored, so when the next time I type `ls -l -a` it is colored.

Just to make it clear, I'm using Windows 10, and then with putty I SSH into a server, where I have an account, and it runs Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the output of `ls` is on the terminal, it stays colored. But if you run `ls` again, whether the output is colored depends on the options you pass to `ls` this time. The `ls` command doesn't remember settings from one time to the next.

If you want to have default settings for a command, define an [alias](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) for it. For bash, the file where aliases are defined is [`.bashrc`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). So add the following line to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

In addition, bash doesn't read `.bashrc` if it's a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell), only if it's an interactive non-login shell. To get the same interactive configuration in both cases, put the following line in your `.bash_profile`:

```
if [ -e ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac   # Load .bashrc if this login shell is interactive
```

For future customizations, [use `.profile` or `.bash_profile` for session startup things like environment variables and `.bashrc` for interactive customizations such as aliases and `shopt` settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085)

If you ever want to run the `ls` program and bypass your alias, run `\ls` instead of `ls`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I did not find any .bashrc file in my user folder, so I created one, and inserted the line of code you suggested. Afterwards, it still remained monochrome instead of colorful.

Comment: @MatX What is the output of `alias` in your shell? Is your shell indeed bash (that's the default on most Linux systems, check the output of `ps $$`)? Does `ls --color=auto` output colors?

Comment: This is the result of the alias command:

alias lp='lp -o nobanner'
alias lpr='lpr -h'
alias md5sum='/usr/local/bin/md5'
alias quota='/usr/local/bin/quota -v'
alias tex2='export PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -e "s/\/opt\/teTeX3\//\/opt\/teTeX2\//g"` ; export MANPATH=`echo $MANPATH | sed -e "s/\/opt\/teTeX3\//\/opt\/teTeX2\//g"`'
alias tex3='export PATH=`echo $PATH | sed -e "s/\/opt\/teTeX2\//\/opt\/teTeX3\//g"` ; export MANPATH=`echo $MANPATH | sed -e "s/\/opt\/teTeX2\//\/opt\/teTeX3\//g"`'

Comment: @MatX The alias isn't present, so either you made a mistake when creating `.bashrc`, or your shell isn't bash. What's the output of `ps $$; cat ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: @MatX Oh, and did you start a new shell? The rc file is only read when the shell starts.

Comment: Thank you for reminding. The result of `ps $$; cat ~/.bashrc` is the following: PID TT S TIME COMMAND 14269 pts/18 S 0:00 -bash alias ls='ls --color=always' And yes, the ls --color=auto command also outputs colors, and yes, I restarted the shell session. Maybe I'm deprived of some rights by the admins? Is that possible? Or does it have to do anything with my default putty settings?

Comment: @MatX Ah, yes, of course, you're logging in over SSH, so you're getting a login shell, and bash unhelpfully loads a different file in that case. Sorry, I should have thought of that, it comes up all the time. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you, man! I applied what you suggested, and it finally solved my problem along with other issues.