# scp and rsync not working when executed within .sh files from "startup programs window"

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, startup, scp

With Ubuntu Mate 16.04,
I have a file `my_backup.sh` like this:

```
# Log just for trying 
echo $(date) >> /home/albert/dia_hora

# BBDD
NOW=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%d")
FILE="cavecanem_production_$NOW.sql"
scp root@46.xxx.xxx.xx4:/home/rails/backup/$FILE /home/albert/druby/copies/cavecanem/bbdd

# Fitxers
rsync -r --ignore-existing root@46.xxx.xxx.xx4:/home/rails/cavecanem/public/fitxers/ /home/albert/druby/copies/cavecanem/public
```

It consists in

1. store a datetime log in dia_hora file (works correctly)
2. Copy with scp (Not Working from startup programs)
3. Copy with rsync (Not Working from startup programs)

If I execute from terminal 
 `sh /home/albert/my_backup.sh` **everything** works correctly (1,2, and 3 parts),

but, if I put in startup programs window a task with: `sh /home/albert/my_backup.sh` **only** executes the first part (*echo $(date) >> /home/albert/dia_hora*)

**Why is it not possible to execute scp or rsync from "startup programs"?**

*Edited on 22/05*:
The problem is that for executing of scp and rsync, it is necessary that .bashrc has to be be executed before, and the startup order is

1. .profile
2. startup programs (ubuntu window, so scp and rsync)
3. .baschrc

Thanks

screenshot in catalan (sorry)

[image]

My .bashrc file:

/* may be the problem where says:  "If not running interactively, don't do anything..."?

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

cd $HOME/druby/cavecanem
export LANGUAGE='en_US.UTF-8 git'
```

My  .profile file:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: Edit your script to include the full path to the `scp` and `rsync` commands.

Comment: scp and rsync may be emitting error messages which you're not seeing. You could capture standard error in your script. Add a line like "exec 2>>/some/file" toward the beginning of the script to direct stderr for the remainder of the script to a file.

Comment: Maybe they depend on some setting that you've put in [`.bashrc` instead of `.profile`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085). What do you have in your `.bashrc`? Dump the environment from the script (`export >>/home/albert/dia_hora`) and compare with the environment in an interactive shell.

Comment: gareth, i've already have the full path.         Kesnter, I've done what you say and the output files of scp and rsync are empty ¿? seems that there aren't errors.

Comment: Gilles. I'm going to do do what you say...but I don't understand, are not both files executed when system starts up?, which one is first?, I'm going to edit the question adding these files Thanks

Comment: The problem is than for executing of scp and rsync, is needed than .bashrc has to be be executed before, and the startup order is 1- .profile 2 -startup programs (ubuntu window, so scp and rsync 2 - .baschrc