# How to set a path variable without root acess?

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, java, path

My college currently uses a very old (like 3 years old) openJDK 1.7 distribution. And being a student, obviously I don't have  root privileges. I wanted to use a much later version downloaded a much more recent version from their official website since one of my app (solr) requires it.

I downloaded the JRE 1.8 and checked the interpreter using

```
saikrishnac@chervil:~/jre18/bin$ ./java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
saikrishnac@chervil:~/jre18/bin$
```

It turned out to be just as expected. Now I want to direct all the java calls made by the app to this bin. But, by default, this is what the university has running

```
saikrishnac@chervil:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)
saikrishnac@chervil:~$
```

So, I'm guessing I need to change the `JAVA_PATH` variable in `/etc/profie`. But I've only read only access and hence I cannot add the following.

```
export JAVA_HOME="path"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The above was suggested at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users

**Summary**

So, is there any workaround for changing the path for just my user account. I mean, when i run java in my account I wish it  executed with the jre18 binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide that you presented tells you how to set these variables globally - for all users. Since you only want to set these for yourself, you should put them in <s>`~/.bashrc`</s> EDIT: As Gilles pointed out in the comment below, `.bashrc` is intended for interactive settings, and few things can go wrong under some circumstances. Instead, you should put them in `.profile`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I answered my own question for someone with the same question :)

Comment: No, [not `.bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells). `.profile` is the place for environment variables, `.bashrc` is for interactive settings. Among the things that can go wrong, `.bashrc` doesn't apply to programs started through a GUI, and overrides changed settings in a sub-session.