# Why can't I add something to PATH permanently?

Tags: environment-variables, path

I am trying to add ruby binaries to my path with this :

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/home/ehsan/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin
```

This works fine in that terminal session and I get :

```
$ rails -v
Rails 5.0.0
```

But after I close that terminal session and open new one and I enter `rails` :

```
$ rails -v
rails : command not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use `export PATH=$PATH:/home/ehsan/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin` and put that line in `~/.bashrc`

Comment: @Rahul No, [not `.bashrc`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085). Don't set environment variables in `.bashrc`.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with setting env vars in ~/.bashrc.  it's useful to set vars etc for both login and non-login environments, and can be sourced from ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PATH` is an environment variable like any other.

To make a permanent change, put it in the startup script for your shell.  e.g. `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or for `bash`.   or `~/.profile` for `bash` and other bourne-like shells.