# Intel C compiler doesn't work with sudo

Tags: sudo, c, intel

I can compile using icc just fine:

> akady@TermintX ~/Test $ icc HelloWorld.c
>
> akady@TermintX ~/Test $ ls
>
> a.out  HelloWorld.c
>
> akady@TermintX ~/Test $ ./a.out
>
> Hello World

But when trying the same thing with sudo:

> akady@TermintX ~/Test $ sudo icc HelloWorld.c
>
> [sudo] password for akady:
>
> sudo: icc: command not found

(Though gcc works fine, both with and without sudo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Seems like `icc` is not in your default path.
2. why compile as root ?

If you REALLY need to compile as root (which i can't think of any reason why) add `icc` path to the `PATH` variable (best place would be in his profile)

```
 export PATH="/opt/intel/blabla/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: I am trying to install openMPI and it gives an error about permissions without using sudo and an error about icc with it, though at a later stage.

Comment: you only need root privileges to install the application to the system, but you don't need it for compiling it.

Comment: The errors come up in the `make all install` stage. It gives a similar error about `icc not found`. I can't figure out just how to go about adding the path to icc, nothing seems to work. Apologies if this is trivial, I am a bit new to linux.

Comment: @Pyrphoros First do `make all` as an ordinary user, then `sudo make install` to install the result. Each argument to `make` is a separate target that you can do independently.

Answer (score -2):

What finally solved the issue was using `sudo -s` and then calling `icc`.

Comment: This makes no difference for me - the `-s` option means "use user's own shell" (either from `$SHELL` or the `passwd` file).  What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using bash.

Comment: Then you should remove your PATH settings from `.bashrc` and put them in `.profile` where they belong. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells and a zillion other similar questions on this site.