# Source .bash_rc when running su in script

Tags: bash, environment-variables, su

I'm writing a script that supposed to be ran with sudo permissions.
But then I need to execute a command from an another user sourcing it's `.bash_rc` where there are some env variables are overloaded and then use it in a command.

For example. I need to print the `PATH` variable for the user:

```
sudo -s -u ${USER_NAME} source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH
```

But instead it prints `PATH` for a user running the script.
I've also tried a lot of other options (with `su` or passing a rcfile) but none of them seems to work.

How could I deal with it?

Comment: Note that no program reads `.bash_rc`, and if you meant `.bashrc` then [you shouldn't define environment variables there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-a-bashrc-equivalent-file-read-by-all-shells/3085#3085).

Answer (score 1):

You've got a `sudo` command that sources a script. You've also got a command that prints `$PATH`. The two are otherwise unrelated.

Perhaps you meant this:

```
sudo -u "${USER_NAME}" bash -c 'source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH'
```

The `-s` can't be used with a compound command, but it could be used with a script containing the two (or more) commands:

```
cat >/opt/bin/show_me_the_path <<'X'
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_rc
echo $PATH
X
chmod a+x /opt/bin/show_me_the_path

sudo -u "${USER_NAME}" -s /opt/bin/show_me_the_path
```

But even that doesn't really make much sense because the script mandates its own shell (`/bin/bash`). All in all it's probably better to rethink the `-s` flag.

Comment: Actually the command `sudo -u "${USER_NAME}" bash -c 'source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH'` does not work. I have a user "zippy" that has a ~/.bash_rc file. The user executing the `sudo` command, "bschuck" does not have that file.
 `bschuck@valhalla:~$ sudo -u zippy bash -c 'source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH'
bash: /home/bschuck/.bash_rc: No such file or directory
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin`
If I add the '-i' option to the sudo command, I don't get the error, but PATH doesn't reflect what was sourced in ~zippy/.bash_rc.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute it as:

```
sudo su - ${USER_NAME} -c 'source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH'
```

An example of it running. The user "zippy" has a ~/.bash_rc file. Note this is in addition to the standard ~/.bashrc file. The user executing the command, "bschuck" does not. The ~zippy/.bash_rc file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
# .bash_rc
PATH=$PATH:/this/is/a/dummy/path
```

Executing this command works:

```
bschuck@valhalla:~$ sudo su - zippy -c 'source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH'
/home/zippy/bin:/home/zippy/.local/bin:\
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:\
/this/is/a/dummy/path
```

Yet this command does not keep the new PATH sourced from the ~zippy/.bash_rc file:

```
bschuck@valhalla:~$ sudo -i -u zippy bash -c 'source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH'
/home/zippy/bin:/home/zippy/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:\
/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:\
/snap/bin
```

If you need to run multiple commands, it's best to put them in a script as I suggested yesterday in a comment to my answer.

Comment: Arrgghh it's that pointless `sudo su` again

Comment: Pointless, but it works. Now perhaps if aside from bashing (see what I did there?) my answer you also contributed a solution to the issue at hand...

Comment: If you put the commands `source ~/.bash_rc; echo $PATH` in a script named /tmp/foo.sh, you can do this:

`sudo -i -u ${USER_NAME} /tmp/foo.sh`