# Program runs from launcher, but not terminal

Tags: terminal, .desktop

I just build and installed paraview. It shows up correctly in the application launcher, and launches just fine when run that way. But when I run paraview from terminal, I get an error: `paraview: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libvtkRenderingMatplotlib-pv5.12.so.1: undefined symbol: PyTuple_Type`

The .desktop file that is generated for paraview uses just `paraview` to launch, with no arguments fed in. How could it possibly work when run via the .desktop file, but not via the terminal? Based on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390501/differences-in-launching-a-program-through-terminal-and-through-an-application-l), it appears that there's different environment variables. This solution doesn't work for me though, the program isn't a text editor, and the `/tmp/env.launcher` file doesn't exist. I'm on Pop_OS! 22.04

Comment: Does your terminal environment contain a `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable?

Comment: Yes, and it includes /usr/local/lib

Comment: Right - so when you run it using the launcher, it's likely finding the correct "system" version of the library instead of your locally-installed one

Comment: But I built it against the locally built one, or at least I ran the build from my shell with that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that should've been used in the build