# Where is cron's PATH set?

Tags: cron, path

Cron doesn't use the path of the user whose crontab it is and, instead, has its own. It can easily be changed by adding `PATH=/foo/bar` at the beginning of the crontab, and the classic workaround is to always use absolute paths to commands run by cron, but where is cron's default PATH defined?

I created a crontab with the following contents on my Arch system (cronie 1.5.1-1) and also tested on an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS box with the same results:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * echo "$PATH" > /home/terdon/fff
```

That printed:

```
$ cat fff
/usr/bin:/bin
```

But why? The default system-wide path is set in `/etc/profile`, but that includes other directories:

```
$ grep PATH= /etc/profile
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
```

There is nothing else relevant in `/etc/environment` or `/etc/profile.d`, the other files I thought might possibly be read by cron:

```
$ grep PATH= /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment
/etc/profile.d/jre.sh:export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
/etc/profile.d/mozilla-common.sh:export MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins"
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:[ -d /usr/bin/site_perl ] && PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/site_perl
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:[ -d /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/bin ] && PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/bin
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:[ -d /usr/bin/vendor_perl ] && PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/vendor_perl
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:[ -d /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/bin ] && PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/bin
/etc/profile.d/perlbin.sh:[ -d /usr/bin/core_perl ] && PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

There is also nothing relevant in any of the files in `/etc/skel`, unsurprisingly, nor is it being set in any `/etc/cron*` file:

```
$ grep PATH /etc/cron* /etc/cron*/*
grep: /etc/cron.d: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.daily: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.hourly: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.monthly: Is a directory
grep: /etc/cron.weekly: Is a directory
/etc/cron.d/0hourly:PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

So, where is cron's default PATH for user crontabs being set? Is it hardcoded in `cron` itself? Doesn't it read some sort of configuration file for this?

Comment: There is no reason for `cron` to look at `/etc/profile`, or care about any particular shell.  A better question is why doesn't `cron` read `PATH` from `login.defs` (on Linux) or `login.conf` (on *BSD).  I suppose it's ultimately an implementation detail.

Comment: @SatōKatsura sure, I only mentioned `/etc/profile` because it uses the same syntax (`var=value`) as `cron` itself, so it would be easy enough to do and `/etc/profile` is, to my knowledge, very widespread. What surprised me is that I couldn't find it being set anywhere so it looked like it was hard coded. As is indeed the case, as Stephen explained below.

Comment: People using `zsh` as their interactive shell don't care about `/etc/profile` (which is specific to `bash`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no, [it is not specific to bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3060/22222) *at all*! Quite the contrary! While there are some shells that don't read it (the c-shell family AFAIK), zsh is not one of them. See the zsh manpage, if you don't believe me. In any case, interactive shells are irrelevant since the various `profile` files are only read by login shells, anyway. These may, or may not be interactive.

Comment: Sometimes running `strings` against a program can help find these hard-coded values, too.

Comment: @Christopher - whether or not `crontab` reads a configuration file is irrelevant to what configuration is used by `cron` itself: `crontab` is just a program that is used to update the database of job tables used by `cron` and signal `cron` when it has changed.  `cron` (if the version in use is anywhere near standard) should be reading `/etc/crontab` at startup.

Comment: @terdon - in *simple* cases, `/etc/profile` uses the same syntax as `cron` for setting the path, but note that it is written in a general purpose programming language that is able to manipulate references to variables and to evaluate generated code, so in the general case extracting the path information from it is much more complex than what `cron` does with its own files.

Comment: @Jules What do you mean? `/etc/profile` should be written in POSIX `sh` and is sourced (`.`) by POSIX compliant (or semi-compliant, like bash, zsh etc.) shells. Given that cron also uses `sh` to run its commands, it would be trivial to source it each time it launches its `sh`.

Comment: @terdon - cron can be configured to use any shell. It can't rely on the user-specified shell being able to understand /etc/profile.

Comment: @Jules it can? How? Calling a command with an explicit shell is not configuring cron, neither is setting a variable in a crontab. `sh` is not the "user-specified" shell, it is the default shell on \*nix systems and is usually either a simple POSIX-compliant shell like `dash`, or actual bourne-sh or `bash` running in POSIX mode. either way, cron *defaults* to `/bin/sh` so it could just as well have *defaulted* to reading `/etc/profile` or, as Sato correctly pointed out, `login.[defs|conf]`.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

It’s hard-coded in [the source code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/blob/52bacc70b592d354efff8231375bf2d51bd4ef52/pathnames.h#L77) (that link points to the current Debian `cron` — given the variety of `cron` implementations, it’s hard to choose one, but other implementations are likely similar):

```
#ifndef _PATH_DEFPATH
# define _PATH_DEFPATH "/usr/bin:/bin"
#endif
```

`cron` doesn’t read default paths from a configuration file; I imagine the reasoning there is that it supports specifying paths already using `PATH=` in any cronjob, so there’s no need to be able to specify a default elsewhere. (The hard-coded default is used [if nothing else specified a path in a job entry](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/cron/blob/52bacc70b592d354efff8231375bf2d51bd4ef52/entry.c#L292).)

Comment: Note that, despite the existence of the `_PATH_DEFPATH_ROOT` define, I confirmed (using a cron job of `echo $PATH > /testfile`) after editing root's crontab using `crontab -e` on Debian Stretch that root's crontab also uses `_PATH_DEFPATH`, i.e. "/usr/bin:/bin", not `_PATH_DEFPATH_ROOT `. This is also confirmed by the second source code link in this answer (in which `_PATH_DEFPATH_ROOT` is not used). It's not clear to me whether this orphaned define is a bug.

Answer (score 13):

Adding to Stephen Kitt's answer, there is a configuration file that sets `PATH` for cron on Ubuntu, and `cron` *ignores* that `PATH` to use the hard-coded default (or `PATH`s set in the crontabs themselves). The file is `/etc/environment`. Note `cron`'s PAM configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/cron
...   
# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session       required   pam_env.so

# In addition, read system locale information
session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale
...
```

This is easily verifiable. Add a variable to `/etc/environment`, say `foo=bar`, run `env > /tmp/foo` as a cronjob and watch as `foo=bar` shows up in the output.

---

> But why? The default system-wide path is set in /etc/profile, but that
>   includes other directories:
>
> ```
> $ grep PATH= /etc/profile
> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"
> ```

That's true in Arch Linux, but in Ubuntu, the base `PATH` is set in `/etc/environment`. Files in `/etc/profile.d` tack on to an existing `PATH`, and you can append to it in `~/.pam_environment`. I have [a bug filed about Arch's behaviour](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/47884).

Unfortunately, `/etc/pam.d/cron` does not include reading from `~/.pam_environment`. Weirdly, `/etc/pam.d/atd` *does* include that file:

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/atd
#
# The PAM configuration file for the at daemon
#

@include common-auth
@include common-account
session    required   pam_loginuid.so
@include common-session-noninteractive
session    required   pam_limits.so
session    required   pam_env.so user_readenv=1
```

... but commands run via `at` apparently inherit the environment available when creating the `at` job (for example, `env -i /usr/bin/at ...` seems to run jobs with a very clean environment).

Amending `/etc/pam.d/cron` to have `user_readenv=1` seems to cause no problems, and variables in `~/.pam_environment` started showing up fine (except for `PATH`, of course).

---

All told, setting environment variables for cron seems to be a messy business. The best place seems to be in the job specification itself, if only because you don't know which inherited environment variables cron might decide ignore (without reading the source).

Comment: Regarding `at` jobs, if you dump an `at` job you’ll see it explicitly sets the environment up to match the environment when the job was created.