# problem with echo IP address

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, variable, echo

I'm trying to create basic script which will be run every minute from cron. Script `script.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
IP=`ifconfig | grep "inet addr" | awk --field-separator ':' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}' | head -1`
echo "$DATE $IP" >> test.log
```

When I run this script by typing "`./script.sh`" I've got IP address in test.log in such format (**and it's ok**):

```
2017-11-08 16:33:33 10.0.0.1
2017-11-08 16:34:33 10.0.0.1
2017-11-08 16:35:33 10.0.0.1
```

However when I create such a cron job:

```
* * * * * /path/to/my/script.sh
```

In test.log I have only date:

```
2017-11-08 16:36:13
2017-11-08 16:37:13
2017-11-08 16:38:13
```

But why? **Why I have no IP address inside?** Do you have any idea?

Comment: `cron` sometimes runs in a different shell and usually in a stripped down environment compared to your user shell, could you  try the same script but replace every call with the absolute path (e.g. `awk` -> `/usr/bin/awk`) , you can use the `which` command to determine the absolute path of an executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`date` is probably `/bin/date` and is in [the default `$PATH` for cron jobs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401621/where-is-crons-path-set/401622#401622), which is not the same as the `$PATH` set on user login.

`ifconfig` is likely `/sbin/ifconfig` which is not in the `$PATH`.

Change `ifconfig` to an explicit full path (such as `/sbin/ifconfig`) to run `ifconfig` within a cron.

Comment: Thank you! Changing to /sbin/ifconfig made a job, thanks :-)