# Command not working when run from cron

Tags: linux, find, cron

I can successfully run this command in the terminal:

`find /home/www/files/1 -type f -name '*' -mtime +180 -exec rm {} \`

However when I add it as a cron job like so:

`*/5 * * * * find /home/www/files/1 -type f -name '*' -mtime +180 -exec rm {} \`

It doesn't work and the system sends a mail saying `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

What can I do to make it work as a cron task?

Comment: use find like this `/usr/bin/find` in the cron

Comment: Are you sure the first version is working? You appear to have a shell escape `\\`` but no actual character (AFAIK it should be `\;` - or optionally `+` if your version of `find` supports it)

Comment: Yes, the first command works as it's written. I will try adding `/usr/bin/find` now.

Comment: I don’t suppose you’re using the fish or rc shell? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/247786

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen cron’s default path should include /usr/bin: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/401621/117549

Comment: I am not aware of fish or rc shell. Added `usr/bin/find` but I still get `usr/bin/find: missing argument to -exec`

Comment: Oh! It works, I think the error might come though if there's no file found to delete, but haven't confirmed yet.

Comment: Two additional notes: what do you think `-name '*'` accomplishes? Also, some versions of find support `-delete`.

Comment: `-name '*'` to delete any file that's older than 180 days. Is it even needed?

Comment: No, `-name '*'` is not needed

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the semi colon at the end of the -exec argument.