# What is the $PATH given to cron jobs?

Tags: cron, path, executable

I have a process that runs on a `@reboot` cron job.  The process needs to run an executable file.  I have noticed that I have to put the executable in `/usr/bin/`.  I can't just put it in a folder in my `$PATH` list.

So my question is, if processes run by cron jobs do not look in the `$PATH` list of directories, where do they look?  Obviously they at least look in `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is cron's PATH set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401621/where-is-crons-path-set)

Comment: You could create a job with `echo "$PATH" >/tmp/cronpath` and get a definitive answer for your environment..

Answer (score 1):

Does this one answer your question sufficiently?:
[Where is cron's PATH set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401621/were-is-crons-path-set) (as per comment)

Check also the comment on the accepted answer.  Have you tried  scheduling a script that prints it's environment variables using a command like `env`? That should get you the answer on your own system, as things can change over time and, of course, we can sometimes (unknowingly) change standard settings when doing something else.