# I am trying to execute a sh script via cronjob but somehow its not working there are no logs shown at least no errors are shown

Tags: shell-script

Hello I am trying to execute a `sh` script via cronjob.
My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $2}')
echo $IP

echo "Verbindung zum Server aufbauen"
```

So what I am trying to do is, I need the IP of my Raspberry Pi and start a server via `ssh`. When I execute the script via terminal it works fine.

Comment: Please present the code of your script using "code sample" formatting. Currently it's not clear how the script actually looks like - for example there is `#!/bin/bash #!/usr/bin/expect -f` on the first line, which seems obviously wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the site. As you can see from some comments (where due to lack for formatting contributors misinterpreted your script has having _two_ shebangs in the first line), please be sure to use the formatting tools when formulating your question. Also if you say "when I execute the script via terminal": Please edit your question to post the exact command-line (do you say `./script.sh` , or `bash script.sh`, or whatever), and state which user you are when running the script via terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Using a double shebang might not work (`#!/bin/bash #!/usr/bin/expect -f`)

You need to set the PATH variable for cronjobs (see [Where is cron's PATH set?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401621/where-is-crons-path-set) )

This should work

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
hostname -I | awk '{print $2}' 
echo "Verbindung zum Server aufbauen"
```