# Cron public IP to log file

Tags: shell-script, cron, logs, date, curl

I want to log my public ip to a file using cron. Something like this:

```
2021-05-17T01:11:46 99.99.99.99
2021-05-17T01:12:46 99.99.99.99
2021-05-17T01:13:46 99.99.99.99
```

Here's what I've cobbled together:

```
* * * * * { date +%FT%T | tr "\n" " "; curl https://ipinfo.io/ip -s ; echo "" ; } >> /home/mario/logs/pubip.log
```

It works* in at sh prompt but once I put the asterisks in front and put it into crontab -e I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

*There's gotta be a more elegant way to handle the formatting. What I frankensteind feels pretty awkward.

Comment: After some more experimenting, removing the "+" argument in the date command gets rid of the error.Cron doesn't like it for some reason. Any ideas why? The same command with the "+" argument works fine from a sh prompt and in a cronjob via bash script

Comment: Or just use a simpler API.. https://api.ipify.org - `curl https://api.ipify.org`

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be the '%' symbols. Should have read the docs more: crontab(5)

```
The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to
       be run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline
       or a "%" character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell
       specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.  A "%" character
       in the command, unless escaped with a backslash (\), will be
       changed into newline characters, and all data after the first %
       will be sent to the command as standard input.
```

Correct cron line that worked in the end is

```
* * * * * { date +\%FT\%T | tr "\n" " "; curl https://ipinfo.io/ip -s ; echo "" ; } >> /home/mario/logs/pubip.log
```

That said, I'll be moving this into a script just for readability's sake as @scimerman suggested.

Comment: `date +"\%FT\%T $(curl https://ipinfo.io/ip -s)"`

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't reproduce your. If the command for cron is too bulky, more elegant way is to wrap it inside a separate cron script and call that from crontab:

```
$ cat ~/crontab.ip 
#!/bin/bash
{ date +%FT%T | tr "\n" " "; curl https://ipinfo.io/ip -s ; echo "" ; } >> ~/log.ip
```

and my crontab is:

```
$ crontab -l
* * * * * ~/crontab.ip
```

It should work.

Comment: Thanks. The script does appear to work fine. Probably similar to the reason why the command works from a shell prompt. I'll likely be doing this since the command is so bulky. 
For educations sake, did you try the non-script way and not get the error I got? I'd still like to know why that's not working. After some testing it appears to be because of the + symbol in the date command. Why would that not work as a cron job?

Answer (score -3):

When putting commands in the cron system, you must use the full path for the command.

I.e.,
***date*** should be ***/bin/date***
***tr*** should be ***/usr/bin/tr***
***curl*** should be ***/usr/bin/curl***.
***echo*** should be ***/usr/bin/echo***

Comment: Couldn't find any reference to this requirement. In fact, crontab(5) lists examples without full paths.

Comment: It's not a requirement - but its a strong recommendation to do so.

Comment: In fact, I recommend against this. In a **highly** stable system that does not get regular updates - sure, it improves security a tiny bit. But in a system that is getting updates regularly, this is NOT ok. Reason #1 is that on some distributions updates sometimes change the location of a binary. This is a breaking change when you're using full paths. Also note that on one of the most stable distros - Debian - this IS an issue. Reason #2 is that this is barely a security issue for when you're using root to execute crons. root's PATH variable is hardly accessible.

Comment: Also, for echo it is generally recommended nowadays that you use the shell function, rather than the binary. In the old days it was recommended so that you use a more "portable" version. But different distributions have it in different locations nowadays - totally not "portable", and also the shell function pretty much has all the options you need on all shells.

Comment: @Fanatique, what does it have to do with security? Its ridiculous to say that not using the full path is LESS secure somehow. What if the path to **echo** was changed in the environment path to **rootkit**? Answer that. You are posting REALLY BAD information.

Comment: @nuifd, you're just telling the root to run certain commands. If the *PATH* envs aren't set to precisely what you want, then you will get unexpected results. That is why you should always use full paths; so that you get the same result every time.

Comment: You seem to misdiagnose the issue in the question.

Comment: @Shōgun8 I have said nowhere in my comment that using full paths is less secure. I've said that the security it provides for root crons is not that important nowadays. If somebody/something else could change the PATH variable for the **root** user, then you have a lot bigger problems. I'm just saying that if you want a stable system that would not introduce breaking changes with updates - don't use full paths. Who will update them when binaries locations change? Who will update them when you switch to a different distro? Sorry to mods if this has to be moved to chat.

Comment: Since cron has [its own, hard-coded PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401621/), many commands will only work if you use the full path to them, @Fanatique.  So it is often a solution to "why is my crontab not running?". However, these are not good examples of, Shogun that since i) `echo` is a shell builtin, so using the full path to the binary instead is not a good idea and ii) all of the example commands you show should be in cron's path. You only need to use the full path for binaries not in `/usr/bin` or `/bin`.

Comment: @ tendon, you base your knowledge of cron on another post? Cron does NOT have it's own hard-coded path, you can set the paths. Please read some documentation. Here is some good documentation, where it states that ***/etc/crontab*** is "empty by default" and to look at acancron man page for more info ->  "https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html. The anacron man page says that this is where you set ***environment assignments***, such as PATH - > https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/anacrontab.5.html.

Comment: @Shōgun8 please read the linked post more carefully. Of course you can change cron's PATH, I never said you couldn't. However, as explained in the linked post (which, by the way references the source code of the cron executable), cron has a hardcoded default PATH which does not depend on the standard PATH set in `/etc/environment` or any of the user-specific configuration files. So, you should either modify the PATH or use the full path to the executable  _when running things that are not in cron's default PATH_. This is not the case for any of the commands listed in your answer.

Comment: ***/etc/crontab is "empty by default"*** ------- This means it has no default PATH

Comment: Sigh. Again, please actually read the answers. They are linking to the actual source code of the program (cron) where you can clearly see the PATH is hardcoded. This has nothing to do with `/etc/crontab` or any other crontab it is about how the cron binary has been compiled.

Comment: You must speaking about the definition in *pathnames.h* where it defines a path as */bin:/usr/bin*if no other path has been selected. ***IF*** any other path has been selected, then it does not define those paths. So there is no assurance that those paths are hardcoded, so then you can't say that any paths are hardcoded.